# Cannot make npm install -g work for my package

Tags: node.js, npm

I am trying to add CLI functionality to my npm package intercept-proxy. I couldn't find any good documentation so I basically copied and modified stuff from express.js.

I added:

```
"bin": {
    "intercept-proxy": "./bin/intercept-proxy"
}
```

...to my package.json file and created a /bin/intercept-proxy.js which contains the CLI stuff.

When I run:

```
npm install -g intercept-proxy
```

... everything works until the linking part. Then it fails, saying:

```
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, chmod 'C:\Users\johan.obrink.24HRCOM\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\intercept-proxy\bin\intercept-proxy
```

... and the log says:

```
381 info linkStuff intercept-proxy@0.2.4
382 verbose linkBins intercept-proxy@0.2.4
383 verbose link bins [ { 'intercept-proxy': './bin/intercept-proxy' },
383 verbose link bins   'C:\\Users\\johan.obrink.24HRCOM\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm',
383 verbose link bins   true ]
384 verbose linkMans intercept-proxy@0.2.4
385 verbose rebuildBundles intercept-proxy@0.2.4
386 verbose rebuildBundles [ 'commander', 'mkdirp', 'underscore' ]
387 info C:\Users\johan.obrink.24HRCOM\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\intercept-proxy unbuild
388 verbose from cache C:\Users\johan.obrink.24HRCOM\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\intercept-proxy\package.json
389 info preuninstall intercept-proxy@0.2.4
390 info uninstall intercept-proxy@0.2.4
391 verbose true,C:\Users\johan.obrink.24HRCOM\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules,C:\Users\johan.obrink.24HRCOM\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules unbuild intercept-proxy@0.2.4
392 verbose C:\Users\johan.obrink.24HRCOM\AppData\Roaming\npm,[object Object] binRoot
393 info postuninstall intercept-proxy@0.2.4
394 error Error: ENOENT, chmod 'C:\Users\johan.obrink.24HRCOM\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\intercept-proxy\bin\intercept-proxy'
395 error If you need help, you may report this log at:
395 error     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
395 error or email it to:
395 error     <npm-@googlegroups.com>
396 error System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
397 error command "c:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "c:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "intercept-proxy"
398 error cwd c:\src
399 error node -v v0.8.9
400 error npm -v 1.1.61
401 error path C:\Users\johan.obrink.24HRCOM\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\intercept-proxy\bin\intercept-proxy
402 error code ENOENT
403 error errno 34
404 verbose exit [ 34, true ]
```

I tried googling ENOENT, chown + Windows but don't seem to get any further.

The full code is up at https://github.com/JohanObrink/intercept-proxy

Edit: I have now tried it on OS X and the problem is the same. Not windows related - just me-being-a-n00b related apparently. Still cannot find what's wrong though.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

ENOENT means no such file or directory.
What happens if you change to this?

```
"bin": {
    "intercept-proxy": "./bin/intercept-proxy.js"
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That was it. Do you by any chance know why express gets away without the .js and I don't?

Comment: And NOW I see that express.js actually named its bin file express - without .js. That's why it worked :/

Comment: Lars, you want to use the 'main', not 'bin'. ex.   "main": "./bin/yomama" (without the JS)

Comment: Yeah, looks like npm does this if you created your package.json automatically with `npm init`.