# npm install errors with Error: ENOENT, chmod

Tags: node.js, permissions, installation, npm, sudo

I am trying to globally install an npm module I just published. Every time I try to install, either from npm or the folder, I get this error.

```
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, chmod '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/takeapeek/lib/cmd.js'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Linux 3.8.0-19-generic
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "takeapeek"
npm ERR! cwd /home/giodamlio
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.6
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.6
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/takeapeek/lib/cmd.js
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/giodamlio/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

I am using sudo and I have triple checked everything in the package everything should work. I did some searching around, and saw a couple of similer cases none of which have been resolved. Here is what I tried.

- Upgrade npm (`sudo npm install -g npm`)
- Clear the global npm cache (`sudo npm cache clear`)
- Clear the user npm cache (`npm cache clear`)

I noticed that the error had to do with the file I am linking to the path, specifically when npm tried to do a chmod. That shouldn't be a problem, my `lib/cli.js` has normal permissions, and npm has superuser permissions during this install.

After digging through the npm docs I found an option that would stop npm from making the bin links(`--no-bin-links`), when I tried the install with it, it worked fine.

So what's the deal? Is this some [weird fringe case bug](https://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues/3311#issuecomment-16011860) that has no solution yet?

**Edit: For reference, [here](https://github.com/giodamelio/takeapeek) is the module I uploaded**

Comment: is your package using node-gyp? I think that no-bin-links call is related if so.

Comment: Nope, no native code in the module. [Here](https://github.com/giodamelio/takeapeek) is the module source for reference.

Comment: The `--no-bin-links` just stops npm from symlinking files in the package.json's `bin` hash to the path on global install.

Comment: Argh, I've definitely run into this before but I can't remember why... will let you know if it pops into my head.

Comment: @jcollum Thanks, its really quite frustrating, I have checked everything a billion times, but I still can't help feeling I've missed something stupid simple. That or maybe it is some weird bug.

Comment: It's something with install paths for dependent libraries I'd bet but that doesn't seem to be relevant for your lib, so I dunno.

Comment: Is this on Linux? Maybe try running "strace npm install ...". Watch for stat or open calls against cmd.js. That might show something interesting, like maybe some directory prefix that isn't displayed.

Comment: are you sure it's not `npm cache clean` instead?

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12964072/1027966

Comment: in my case, the scenario is different but I had the same bug `npm ERR! code ENOENT`. the solution was `cd .. && ls` because I don't know how but I deleted the directory but bash terminal still was on that directory so this is why. so by using `cd..` I go outside the deleted repo, then with `ls` I checked if I was in the correct directory or not. if you are in the correct one then you can copy and paste your `npm create` and what you want fine. this is just what happened to me... your scenario is different of course, this was only my experience. so TLDR: check if you are in the correct 

Answer (score 178, accepted):

Ok it looks like NPM is using your `.gitignore` as a base for the `.npmignore` file, and thus ignores `/lib`. If you add a blank `.npmignore` file into the root of your application, everything should work.

A better, more explicit approach is to use an allow-list rather than a disallow-list, and use the "files" field in package.json to specify the files in your package.

[edit] - more info on this behaviour here: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/using-npm/developers#keeping-files-out-of-your-package

Comment: Darn, that must be it. That seems like a bit of a confusing way of doing things. Not at a computer now, but I will try it in a few hours.

Comment: Yea it took me a while to figure it out. Some guys more experienced than I hinted this on the reddit thread.

Comment: I tested this using your repo and installing locally using `npm install ../takeapeek` and adding the blank .npmignore file works.

Comment: 3 hours of frustration came down to one line in my .gitignore that was freaking out the npm install -g.  Insane.

Comment: 'type NUL > .npmignore' for windows

Comment: As of npm@5, the npm cache self-heals from corruption issues and data extracted from the cache is guaranteed to be valid. If you want to make sure everything is consistent, use 'npm cache verify' instead.

Comment: remove package-lock.json file

Comment: also - worth of shot - try running it as admin

Answer (score 130):

I ran into a similar problem,

```
npm cache clean
```

solved it.

Comment: I tried `npm cache verify` and it worked. thanks for hint.

Answer (score 25):

I was getting this error on npm install and adding .npmignore did not solve it.

> Error: ENOENT, stat 'C:\Users\My-UserName\AppData\Roaming\npm'

I tried going to the mentioned folder and it did not exist. 
The error was fixed when I **created** **npm** folder in **Roaming** folder.

This is on Windows 8.1

Comment: Thx you for saving people time!

Comment: On Windows 10 THIS was also the answer ! THX

Answer (score 16):

This problem somehow arose for me on Mac when I was trying to run `npm install -g bower`. It was giving me a number of errors for not being able to find things like graceful-fs. I'm not sure how I installed npm originally, but it looks like perhaps it came down with node using homebrew. I first ran

```
brew uninstall node
```

This removed both `node` and `npm` from my path. From there I just reinstalled it

```
brew install node
```

When it completed I had `node` and `npm` on my path and I was able to run

```
rm -rf ~/.npm
npm install -g bower
```

This then installed bower successfully.

Updating the brew formulas and upgrading the installs didn't seem to work for me, I'm not sure why. The removal of the `.npm` folder was something that had worked for other people, and I had tried it without success. I did it this time just in case. Note also that neither of the following solved the problem for me, although it did for others:

```
npm cache clean
sudo npm cache clean
```

Answer (score 12):

I encountered similar behavior after upgrading to npm `6.1.0`.  It seemed to work once, but then I got into a state with this error while trying to install a package that was specified by path on the filesystem:

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! syscall rename
```

The following things **did not fix the problem**:

- `rm -rf node_modules`
- `npm cache clean` (gave `npm ERR! As of npm@5, the npm cache self-heals`....`use 'npm cache verify' instead.`)
- `npm cache verify`
- `rm -rf ~/.npm`

How I **fixed the problem**:

- `rm package-lock.json`

Answer (score 10):

I got this error while trying to install a grunt plugin. i found i had an outdated version of npm and the error went away after updating npm to the latest version

```
npm install -g npm
```

Answer (score 6):

Delete package-lock.json file then run `npm install`

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem, and just found a handling not mentioned here. Though I'd contribute to the community:

`npm install -g myapp` was not copying the `bin` directory. I found this to be because I did not include it in the `files` in my `package.json`

```
"files": [
  "lib",
  "bin" // this was missing
]
```

Comment: Got the same issue and this answer was the only good fix for me. The reason was I got the `files` key in my `package.json` with some entries like `index.js` and `LICENSE`, but not the `bin` folder. So it works if there is no `files` key at all, or if there is a `files` key AND the `bin` folder into.

Comment: Thanks, this helped me get unstuck. Once you pointed out that the bin directory wasn't included in files I thought "oh! of course!". Then I went back to the docs to see if I missed it and it's not mentioned (at least not in the npm blog post I was reading through). At least I'm not crazy :P. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Thanks. I've updated my answer to mention the "files" approach which imo is a better approach.

Answer (score 4):

I was getting a similar error on `npm install` on a local installation:

```
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '[path/to/local/installation]/node_modules/grunt-contrib-jst'
```

I am not sure what was causing the error, but I had recently installed a couple of new node modules locally, upgraded node with homebrew, and ran 'npm update -g'.

**The only way I was able to resolve the issue was to delete the local node_modules directory entirely and run `npm install` again:**

```
cd [path/to/local/installation]
npm rm -rdf node_modules
npm install
```

Answer (score 4):

I have a similar problem specifucally :
ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, chmod 'node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/node_modules/http-signature/node_modules/sshpk/bin/sshpk-conv
I tried all above solutions but no luck.
I was using vagrant box, and the project was in a shared folder. The problems seems to be only there, when I move the project to another not shared folder (woth host), voila! problem solved.
Just in case another person was using also vagrant

Comment: You waked me from a nightmare, tnx!
I have 2 additions:
1.) Stop using npm, use Yarn.
2.) Run npm from your HOST machine and not the VM.

Answer (score 4):

I got the simple solution, just clear the `npm cache`.

```sh
sudo npm cache clear --force
```

then remove the `node_modules` & `package-lock.json`

```sh
sudo rm -rf node_modules
```

```sh
sudo rm -rf package-lock.json
```

Now install the dependencies module using npm and start the server

```sh
npm install && npm start
```

Answer (score 3):

I got a similar error message when trying to `npm install` a bunch of dependencies. Turns out some of them fail to install on Debian/Ubuntu because they expect `/usr/bin/node` to be the node executable. To fix, you need do

```
sudo ln -s nodejs /usr/bin/node
```

or better yet,

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs-legacy
```

For more info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21171188/7581

Answer (score 2):

I think your compiled coffee script is missing from the published npm package. Try writing a [prepublish](https://npmjs.org/doc/scripts.html) command.

Comment: Nope, the lib folder was there when I published it. Besides, I get the same error when I try to install from the local folder. Even when the lib folder is there.

Comment: @giodamelio I agree with ryan on this one. The error is saying `takeapeek/lib/cmd.js` does not exist. Even though the lib folder might be 'there' when you publish, it's not going to be 'there' when you install via npm unless it's part of the repository, or unless you use prepublish to create it.

Answer (score 2):

In my case (multiple code ENOENT errno 34) problem was with `~/.npm/` directory access. Inside it there were some subdirs having `root:root` rights, which were causing problems while I run commands as normal user (without `sudo`). So I changed ownership of all subdirs and files inside `~/.npm/` dir into my local user and group. That did the trick on my Ubuntu (on Mac should work too).

```
$ sudo chown yourusername.yourgroupname ~/.npm/ -R
```

You should know your user name, right? If no then run `$ whoami` and substitute your group name with it too, like this:

```
$ sudo chown johnb.johnb ~/.npm/ -R
```

EDIT:

**Test case**:

From my local account `/home/johnb` I npm-installed globally some generator for `yeoman`, like this:

```
$ sudo npm install -g generator-laravel
```

**Problem nature**:

Above action caused some dependencies being installed inside `~/.npm/` dir, having `root:root` ownership (because of `sudo ...`). Evidently npm does not run as local user (or change dependencies subdirs ownership afterwards) when pulling dependencies and writing them to a local user subdir `~/.npm/`.
As long as npm would be so careless against fundamental unix filesystem security issues the problem would reoccur.

**Solution**:

1. Continuosly check if `~/.npm/` contains subdirs with ownership (and/or permissions) other than your local user account, especially when you install or update something with `sodo` (root). If so, change the ownership inside `~/.npm/` to a local user recursively.
2. Ask `npm, bower, grunt, ...` community that they address this issue as I described it above.

Answer (score 2):

Had a similar Issue but I was in wrong directory please cross check the path of thee file & the run npm start

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

I tried all the stuff I found on the net (`npm cache clear` and `rm -rf ~/.npm`), but nothing seems to work. What solved the issue was updating node (and npm) to the latest version. Try that.

Answer (score 1):

In Windows I had a similar error.
Search paste App Data and search for the string `npm`.

I replaced the string `'npm'` (including quotes) with `'npm.cmd'` in both `atlasboard\lib\package-dependency-manager.js` and `atlasboard\lib\cli\commands.js`. That fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The same error during global install (`npm install -g mymodule`) for package with a non-existing script.

In package.json:

```json
    ...
    "bin": {
      "module": "./bin/module"
    },
    ...
```

But the `./bin/module` did not exist, as it was named `modulejs`.

Answer (score 1):

1. Install latest version of node
2. Run: npm cache clean
3. Run: npm install cordova -g

Answer (score 1):

You can get this error if your node.js is corrupted somehow as well. I fixed this error by uninstall/restart/install node.js completely and it fixed this error, along with the three other mysterious errors that are thrown.

Answer (score 1):

Be careful with invalid values for keys "directories" and "files" in package.json

If you start with a new application, and you want to start completely blank, you have to 
either start in a complete empty folder or have a valid package.json file in it.

If you do not want to create a package.json file first, just type: `npm i some_package`

Package with name "some_package" should be installed correctly in a new sub folder "node_modules".

If you create a package.json file first, type: `npm init`
Keep all the defaults (by just clicking ENTER), you should end up with a valid file.

It should look like this:

```
{
  "name": "yourfoldername",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

Note that the following keys are missing: "*directories*", "*repository*" and "*files*". It looks like if you use incorrect values for "*directories*" and/or "*files*", you are not able to install the package. Leaving these keys out, solved the issue for me.

Also note key "*main*". This one is present, but it does contain an invalid value. No file "index.js" exists (yet). You can safely remove it.

Now type: `npm i some_package`
and package with name "some_package" should be installed correctly in a new sub folder "node_modules".

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar error with npm in a docker container for webpack. The issue was caused by the --user command line argument of docker run, because the given user and group in there somehow messed up the rights on the local volume. Hope this helps someone :)

Answer (score 1):

Tried nearly everything then finally this:

Simply remove node_modules then run `'npm install'` again

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on ubuntu, and got rid of the problem by closing the terminal and opening a new one.

Comment: this worked with me on widows after I deleted my node_modules and reinstalled it (idk if that was needed), weird error and weird solution

Answer (score 1):

It's because there is no package.json and only package-lock.json

Try: npm init --yes

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with a different cause: the `yo node` generator had added `"files": ["lib/"]` to my `package.json` and because my `cli.js` was outside of the `lib/` directory, it was getting skipped when publishing to npm.

(Yeoman issue at https://github.com/yeoman/generator-node/issues/63 it should be fixed soon.)

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the error "Error: ENOENT, stat 'C:\Users\userName\AppData\Roaming\npm'. But there was no such directory. Created the directory and the npm install started working

Answer (score 0):

I recently upgraded to node 4.2.1 on a Windows 7 x64 machine. When running

```
npm install -g bower
```

I got a similar error:

> npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\THE_USERNAME\AppData\Local\Temp\npm-THE_HASH'

Thinking it was related to the AppData path, I played around with

```
npm config edit
```

and

```
npm config edit --global
```

to change the prefix, cache and tmp fields but received the same error with the new paths:

> npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\THE_USERNAME\npm-temp\npm-THE_HASH'

All commands were run as Administrator, so I had full permissions.

Then I thought there were some issues with existing files so I ran:

```
npm cache clean
```

But got the same error. However, there were still some temp files lying around. Manually removing all temp data with cygwin finally fixed the problem for me:

```
rm -rf bower bower.cmd node_modules etc
```

If you only have Windows cmd, you could use something like

```
rmdir /S THE_TEMP_DIR
```

to remove all subdirectories (although if you have deeply nested node dependencies, this is notoriously problematic)

So, maybe there is some issues with upgrading npm and having versions of bower or other packages hanging around. In my case that seemed to be the problem

Answer (score 0):

While installing ionic I got below error

> 115648 error enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename
>   'C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules.staging\ansi-b11f0c4b'
>   -> 'C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\ansi'

There was no folder called `ansi` at that path.  I created it there and it installed correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If you tried to "make install" in your project directory with this error you can try it:

```
rm -rf ./node_modules
npm cache clear
npm remove sails
```

then you can try to "make install"

If you have the "npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, chmod '.../djam-backend/node_modules/js-beautify/js/bin/css-beautify.js'" then you can try to install some previous version of the js-beautify, more comments: https://github.com/beautify-web/js-beautify/issues/1247

```
"dependencies": {
  ...
  "js-beautify": "1.6.14"
  ...
}
```

and the run "make install". It seem works in case if you have not other dependencies that requires higher version (1.7.0) in this case you must downgrade this packages also in the packages.json.

or

Answer (score 0):

None of the above worked for me. But `yarn install` worked, then `npm i` started working. Not sure what yarn fixed, but quick and easy solution!

Answer (score 0):

First do

```
 npm rm -rdf node_modules
```

then do

```
npm install
```

After that install whatever files you want to add

Answer (score 0):

Closing Android Studio solved this error for me.

Answer (score 0):

node_modules directory could be opened in another application  like "neatbeans"  and file creation/renaming is forbidden

ridiculously -- on windows 10 machine -- that was my only problem

Answer (score 0):

First install mongoose dependencies

> npm install mongoose

> npm install

Answer (score 0):

Solve the problem simply because the modification to the file is locked, or you have locked the permissions on the partition through a specific protection program, and evidence of that is to create the project in another file or another place on the hard drive

Answer (score 0):

Remove node_modules, package-lock.json and run npm install

```
rm -rf node_modules
rm -rf package-lock.json
npm install
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm also having trouble with React 17.0.2, because right now by default installation is React 18.

How I'm dealing with this node/npm error is by:

1. uninstall and installing back nodejs
2. Don't delete the package-lock.json
3. run: npm install

It works for me: Windows 10, npm 8.6.0, node v16.14.2

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31520531)

Answer (score 0):

Following commands worked for me :

```
           npm cache clean --force
           npm rm -rdf node_modules
           rm -rf package-lock.json
           npm install -g @sencha/ext-gen
           npm install
```

Answer (score 0):

To resolve the following error, please ensure you are running `npm run start` command in the right directory on your terminal.

```
$ npm run start
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path E:\YOUR_PROJECT_FOLDER\example-frontend/package.json
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'E:\YOUR_PROJECT_FOLDER\example-frontend\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error until I discovered I was running "npm start" in the wrong directory. After that, it worked well when I navigated to the correct directory by `cd <directory-name>`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

- Delete node modules
- Delete package-lock.json
- `sudo npm install`

Answer (score 0):

1. `npm uninstall -g create-react-app`
2. `npx clear-npx-cache`

   **then**
3. `npx create-react-app app-name`

Answer (score 0):

In VS code there is run option in the bottom left, to resolve this issue, click that and select Node.js and then select "Run Script: Start (React)"

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

Answer (score 0):

This is the error i face when typing `npm install`

npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall stat
npm ERR! path C:\Users\GENERAL STORES\AppData\Local\npm-cache_cacache\content-v2\sha512\2d\61\54631522b961740001938687df5b59f84c915a9faabb576d7e36f12c51fb39360a1cd65623322a750725d670d672973c1a5d3c558a18def90f27ddf61d79
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! enoent Invalid response body while trying to fetch https://registry.npmjs.org/normalize-range: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'C:\Users\GENERAL STORES\AppData\Local\npm-cache_cacache\content-v2\sha512\2d\61\54631522b961740001938687df5b59f84c915a9faabb576d7e36f12c51fb39360a1cd65623322a750725d670d672973c1a5d3c558a18def90f27ddf61d79'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\GENERAL STORES\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2024-01-08T11_04_18_446Z-debug-0.log

to solve it, i commented `/node_modules` in the `.gitignore` file like this:

> /.phpunit.cache
> `# /node_modules`
> /public/build
> /public/hot
> /public/storage
> /storage/*.key
> /vendor
> ...

then retype the command `npm install`

Answer (score -1):

I have came across similar issue, clearing cache, deleting node_modules and reinstalling didn't work, so upgrading the node version to latest one worked for me.

```
sudo npm install n -g
```

then

```
sudo n stable
```

Answer (score -2):

```
Creating a new React app in C:\Users\CM\Downloads\react\github-profile.
Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts...

npm ERR! path C:\Users\CM\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_cacache\content- 

v2\sha512\36\c6\c3e97514319bc1c6d40026e58325e782e1016c996b1fa335b1
0893d67f7339e4af62bb688c0da2aaca839d4c9d51e2eb015eec65545008a3cad93d00f806

npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! errno -4048
npm ERR! syscall lstat
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, lstat 
'C:\Users\CM\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_cacache\content- 
v2\sha512\36\c6\c3e97514319bc1c6d40026e58325e782e1016c996
b1fa335b10893d67f7339e4af62bb688c0da2aaca839d4c9d51e2eb015eec6
5545008a3cad93d00f806'
npm ERR! { [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, lstat 
'C:\Users\CM\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_cacache\content- 
v2\sha512\36\c6\c3e97514319bc1c6d40026e58325e782e1016c996b1f 
a335b10893d67f7339e4af62bb688c0da2aaca839d4c9d51e2eb015eec6554500
8a3cad93d00f806']

npm ERR! cause:
npm ERR! { Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, lstat 
'C:\Users\CM\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_cacache\content- 
v2\sha512\36\c6\c3e97514319bc1c6d40026e58325e782e1016c996b1
fa335b10893d67f7339e4 
af62bb688c0da2aaca839d4c9d51e2eb015eec65545008a3cad93d00f806'
npm ERR! errno: -4048,
npm ERR! code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR! syscall: 'lstat',
npm ERR! path:
npm ERR! 'C:\Users\CM\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_cacache\content- 


npm ERR! stack:
npm ERR! 'Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, lstat 
'C:\Users\CM\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_cacache\content- 
v2\sha512\36\c6\c3e97514319bc1c6d40026e58325e782e1016c996
b1fa335b10893d67f7339e4af62bb688c0da2aaca839d4c9d51e2eb015
eec65545008a3cad93d00f806'',
npm ERR! errno: -4048,
npm ERR! code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR! syscall: 'lstat',
npm ERR! path:
npm ERR! 'C:\Users\CM\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_cacache\content- 
v2\sha512\36\c6\c3e97514319bc1c6d40026e58325e782e1016c996b1fa335
b10893d67f7339e4af62bb688c0da2aaca839d4c9d51e2eb015eec65545008a3cad93
d00f806',
npm ERR! parent: 'postcss-image-set-function' }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It's possible that the file was already in use (by a
text editor or antivirus),
npm ERR! or that you lack permissions to access it.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double- 
check thenpm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or 
try  running

npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator (though this is not 
recommended).
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR! C:\Users\CM\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2019-03-22T10_
27_19_722Z-debug.log


Aborting installation.
npm install --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom react- 
scripts   has failed.

Deleting generated file... node_modules
Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting GitHub-profile/ from C:\Users\CM\Downloads\reactDone.``
```

i was facing similar error but i tried to run create-react-app command many times and finally it was created , this was the problem with my internet connection.
check your internet connection

Answer (score -17):

Please try this

```
SET HTTP_PROXY=<proxy_name>
```

Then try that command.It will work

Comment: where do I put this?