# npm install -g yo error

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm

my dev machine is

cat /etc/issue

```
Ubuntu 14.04 LTS \n \l
```

but the issue is when I run

```
sudo npm install -g yo
```

i get

```
> yo@1.1.2 postinstall /home/shajahan/npm/lib/node_modules/yo
> node ./scripts/doctor

sh: 1: node: not found
npm WARN This failure might be due to the use of legacy binary "node"
npm WARN For further explanations, please read
/usr/share/doc/nodejs/README.Debian

npm ERR! weird error 127
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

I can't even run

```
~/js-sandbox$ yo webapp
yo: command not found
```

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/21171188/1520671

Comment: I think it works now, I had to bunch of purge and install on apt-get in order to get "yo" installed and in a working condition.