# gulp command does not work

Tags: ubuntu, gulp

I am using ubuntu 14.04 LTS, I have nodejs (not node) and npm installed. 
I had installed gulp using `npm install gulp -g`.

But my command gulp does not work, it runs silently returning nothing!

[image]

Comment: can you show how you are calling gulp on the command line?

Comment: I just ran "gulp -v" but it does not show any info not even any error messages. @BeNdErR

Comment: What's the output of the `which gulp` command?

Comment: @RaphDG, "gulp" or "gulp -v" does not return anything.

Comment: What about "which gulp" ?

Comment: @RaphDG, it returns.
/usr/local/bin/gulp

Comment: And what about "which nodejs" ?

Comment: output shows => /usr/bin/nodejs

Answer (score 40):

I ran into the same problem today on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.  After debugging I noticed that I had accidentally installed nodejs and node using apt-get.  After running

`sudo apt-get remove node`

the problem was fixed.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Worked for me after following RaphDG, daniels, then jmw327 response's in that order! TY.

Comment: gulp needs node (`#!/usr/bin/env node`) so how can removing it solve the problem? Can you explain this a bit more? If I follow this advice I quite rightly get `/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory`

Comment: Never mind. I found the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21168141/cannot-install-packages-using-node-package-manager-in-ubuntu

Answer (score 34):

Try linking the `nodejs` executable to `node` in the same path.

Something like:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node
```

Depending on where your node executable is. You can find out with

```
which nodejs
```

Comment: problem still persists :( "gulp" or "gulp -v" do nothing.

Comment: Have you tried this `sudo ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node` ?

Comment: It says, 
ln: failed to create symbolic link ‘/usr/bin/node’: File exists

Comment: Don't forget to run `npm install gulp -g` again afterwards

Comment: If you have, say, $HOME/bin earlier in your path than the location of node, you can ln -s $(which nodejs) $HOME/bin/node without the sudo. Note that gulp-cli expects gulp to be installed locally, not globally (that is, omit -g).

Answer (score 21):

On my side, same symptom. What was missing is th CLI part of gulp:

```
sudo npm install --global gulp-cli
```

Comment: You must not use "sudo" while installing any package, as it creates problems,....try it without sudo!

Comment: Worked for me with `sudo`. Without `sudo` it says `npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.`

Answer (score 17):

When you have these kind of problem, my advice is to **reinstall** the module :

```
npm un -g gulp && npm un gulp
npm i -g gulp
npm i --save-dev gulp
```

These commands uninstall all gulp modules in local and global.

After, it installs gulp **in global** to use it in the **command line**, 
and in your **local modules**, because gulp needs it as well.

Comment: Works for me too.

Answer (score 2):

You can Install gulp by using terminal(`npm install -g gulp`). But best way is use [Synaptic Package Manager](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SynapticHowto). This is old Software installer of Ubuntu. but now Ubuntu Introduce [Ubuntu Software Center](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/software-center/).

Cz of I recommended `Synaptic` is when you install some software it will download some of helpers too. Ex if you want download `gulp(Node.js)` in search type node.js. It will show some other apps too. Select all and click apply.

1. To download Synaptic

   - `sudo apt-get install synaptic`
2. To install `Node.js` too.
3. To check node version

   - `node --version`
4. To run `gulp`,  Go to the directory and just type `gulp`.

It will load all your project

---

### Update 2017-10-14

To install complete node, follow these

1. Remove node(if exist) `sudo apt-get remove nodejs` [Check this as well](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41057802/4595675)
2. Remove npm(if exist)  `sudo apt-get remove npm`
3. Clean `sudo apt-get autoremove`
4. `sudo apt-get update`
5. `sudo apt-get install nodejs`
6. `sudo apt-get install npm`

now check command `gulp`

`

Answer (score 0):

even after uninstalling and installing nodejs and npm kept getting 
"/usr/bin/env: ‘node’: No such file or directory"

so i checked the node version (not nodejs): 
**node -v** 
got
"The program 'node' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt install nodejs-legacy"

so i did install it:
**sudo apt install nodejs-legacy**

and gulp works fine.