# How can I completely uninstall nodejs, npm and node in Ubuntu

Tags: node.js, ubuntu

The Question is similar to [How do I completely uninstall Node.js, and reinstall from beginning (Mac OS X)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177954/how-do-i-completely-uninstall-node-js-and-reinstall-from-beginning-mac-os-x) but for Ubuntu, and just for uninstalling.

Installation was done by: `sudo apt-get install node`

How do I completely remove npm along with all libraries, packages and any other files installed by npm on my system, via e.g. `npm install -g @vue/cli`?

I do plan to reinstall npm afterwards.

Comment: installing nodejs-legacy works if you first `apt-get remove node` (or better yet, purge). The node program is a ham radio software modem so unless you have a ham license and want to send digital packets over ham radio you don't need it.

Comment: yeah, I did it. Still I had problems. Everytime I wrote `node` in the console it would tell me something like `/usr/sbin/ couldn't finde node` or something like that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Uninstall Node.JS using Linux command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5650169/uninstall-node-js-using-linux-command-line)

Answer (score 570, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get remove nodejs
sudo apt-get remove npm
```

Then go to `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` and remove any node list if you have. Then do a

```
sudo apt-get update
```

**Check for any `.npm` or `.node` folder in your home folder and delete those.**

If you type

```
which node
```

you can see the location of the node. Try `which nodejs` and `which npm` too.

I would recommend installing node using Node Version Manager(NVM). That saved a lot of headache for me. You can install nodejs and npm without `sudo` using nvm.

Comment: Adding to this, I will also suggest you to remove any 3rd part PPAs if you have added them. I was stuck at this problem, node was getting removed but still I was unable to install a newer version without using `nvm`

Comment: Only this worked for me! I just add the next command in the end: `rm -rf usr/local/bin/npm`

Comment: If you want to remove `nvm` too check this issue https://github.com/creationix/nvm/issues/298

Comment: answer above assumes that this was not installed using the node script and wget.... @zanna has name on both solutions, and the two should be combined

Comment: @LeeRuns I only edited them. I agree there is a lot of duplication on this post - I think three nearly identical answers have already been removed. I don't think I can do anything further with the tools available to me.

Comment: REMEMBER, it's `nodejs` and not `node`. I tried `apt remove node` but it couldnt find the package. but when I tried `apt remove nodejs` it worked

Comment: "you can see the location of the node. Try which nodejs and which npm too." What's your meaning on this? Since you still could see the node file, your solution to uninstall is still not complete, right?

Comment: @dani24 adding onto your point, run this command with root privileges using `sudo`

Comment: Awesome. Can you please add some code at the end about how to install node using nvm - or a link - thx.

Answer (score 195):

It is better to remove NodeJS and its modules manually because installation leaves a lot of files, links and modules behind and later this creates problems when we reconfigure another version of NodeJS and its modules.

To remove the files, run the following commands:

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/npm 
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/share/man/man1/node* 
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/dtrace/node.d
rm -rf ~/.npm
rm -rf ~/.node-gyp
sudo rm -rf /opt/local/bin/node
sudo rm -rf /opt/local/include/node
sudo rm -rf /opt/local/lib/node_modules
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/node*
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/include/node*
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/node*
```

I have posted a step by step guide with commands on my blog: [AMCOS IT Support For Windows and Linux: To completely uninstall node js from Ubuntu](https://web.archive.org/web/20161114130923/http://amcositsupport.blogspot.in/2016/07/to-completely-uninstall-node-js-from.html).

Comment: Perfect, I've just added "sudo rm -rf ~/.npm-global"

Comment: Under what circumstances would a system-installed Node write things in `/opt`, let alone then `/usr/local`?

Comment: I also needed 'sudo apt-get remove nodejs'

Comment: plus ``apt autoremove`` ?

Answer (score 151):

Note: This will completely remove nodejs from your system; then you can make a fresh install from the below commands.

Removing Nodejs and Npm

```
sudo apt-get remove nodejs npm node
sudo apt-get purge nodejs
```

Now remove `.node` and `.npm` folders from your system

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/npm 
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/share/man/man1/node* 
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/dtrace/node.d 
sudo rm -rf ~/.npm 
sudo rm -rf ~/.node-gyp 
sudo rm -rf /opt/local/bin/node 
sudo rm -rf opt/local/include/node 
sudo rm -rf /opt/local/lib/node_modules  

sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/node*
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/include/node*
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/node*
```

Go to home directory and remove any node or `node_modules` directory, if exists.

You can verify your uninstallation by these commands; they should not output anything.

```
which node
which nodejs
which npm
```

Installing NVM (Node Version Manager) by downloading and running a script

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.34.0/install.sh | bash
```

The command above will clone the NVM repository from Github to the `~/.nvm` directory:

Close and reopen your terminal to start using nvm or run the following to use it now:

```sh
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion
```

As the output above says, you should either close and reopen the terminal or run the commands to add the path to nvm script to the current shell session. You can do whatever is easier for you.

Once the script is in your PATH, verify that nvm was properly installed by typing:

```
nvm --version
```

which should give this output:

```
0.34.0
```

Installing Node.js and npm

```
nvm install node
nvm install --lts
```

Once the installation is completed, verify it by printing the Node.js version:

```
node --version
```

should give this output:

```
v12.8.1
```

Npm should also be installed with node, verify it using

```
npm -v
```

should give:

```
6.13.4
```

Extra - [Optional]
You can also use two different versions of node using nvm easily

nvm install 8.10.0 # just put the node version number
Now switch between node versions

```
$ nvm ls
->     v12.14.1
        v13.7.0
default -> lts/* (-> v12.14.1)
node -> stable (-> v13.7.0) (default)
stable -> 13.7 (-> v13.7.0) (default)
iojs -> N/A (default)
unstable -> N/A (default)
lts/* -> lts/erbium (-> v12.14.1)
lts/argon -> v4.9.1 (-> N/A)
lts/boron -> v6.17.1 (-> N/A)
lts/carbon -> v8.17.0 (-> N/A)
lts/dubnium -> v10.18.1 (-> N/A)
```

In my case v12.14.1 and v13.7.0 both are installed, to switch I have to just use

```
nvm use 12.14.1
```

Configuring npm for global installations
In your home directory, create a directory for global installations:

```
mkdir ~/.npm-global
```

Configure npm to use the new directory path:

```
npm config set prefix '~/.npm-global'
```

In your preferred text editor, open or create a `~/.profile` file if does not exist and add this line:

```
PATH="$HOME/.npm-global/bin:$PATH"
```

On the command line, update your system variables:

```
source ~/.profile
```

That's all

Comment: This is the most comprehensive answer to removing old versions, and using NVM to make intalling the latest version easier.

Comment: If you face the error `Provided file to checksum does not exist.
` Please view [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67633785/nvm-can-not-install-nodejs-on-ubuntu-18-04)

Comment: Perfect! This was butter smooth.

Comment: You can either `Reinstall npm with a node version manager (recommended) or Manually change npm's default directory`. Doing both is unnecessary `https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally`

Answer (score 7):

Those who installed node.js via the package manager can just run:

```
sudo apt-get purge nodejs
```

Optionally if you have installed it by adding the official NodeSource repository as stated in [*Installing Node.js via package manager*](https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/), do:

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nodesource.list
```

If you want to clean up npm cache as well:

```
rm -rf ~/.npm
```

---

**It is bad practice to try to remove things manually, as it can mess up the package manager, and the operating system itself. This answer is completely safe to follow**

Comment: I don't like the manual way to delete things too. thank for this

Answer (score 7):

> It bothered me too much while updating node version from 8.1.0 to
> 10.14.0

Here is what worked for me:

1. Open terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>).
2. Type `which node`, which will give a path something like `/usr/local/bin/node`
3. Run the command `sudo rm /usr/local/bin/node` to remove the binary (adjust the path according to what you found in step 2). Now `node -v` shows you have no node version
4. Download a script and run it to set up the environment:

   ```
   curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | sudo -E bash -
   ```
5. Install using `sudo apt-get install nodejs`

   Note: If you are getting error like

   ```
   node /usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
   ```

   just run

   ```
   ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node
   ```

   [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20886217/browserify-error-usr-bin-env-node-no-such-file-or-directory)
6. Now `node -v` will give `v10.14.0`

Worked for me.

Answer (score 6):

I was crazy to delete node and npm and nodejs from my Ubuntu 14.04 but with this steps you will remove it:

```
sudo apt-get uninstall nodejs npm node
sudo apt-get remove nodejs npm node
```

If you uninstall correctly and it is still there, check these links:

- [Stack Overflow answer with more information](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11178106)
- [Remove npm - Official website](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/removing-npm)
- [Stack Overflow answer for uninstalling if you installed via git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31573083)
- [Try purging nodejs npm and node](https://askubuntu.com/a/786019)

You can also try using `find`:

```
find / -name "node"
```

Although since that is likely to take a long time and return a lot of confusing false positives, you may want to search only PATH locations:

```
find $(echo $PATH | sed 's/:/ /g') -name "node"
```

It would probably be in `/usr/bin/node` or `/usr/local/bin`. After finding it, you can delete it using the correct path, eg:

```
sudo rm /usr/bin/node
```

Answer (score -7):

Try the following commands:

```
$ sudo apt-get install nodejs
$ sudo apt-get install aptitude
$ sudo aptitude install npm
```

Comment: The main difference between your answer and the accepted answer from a few years ago is that you're going through Aptitude. It'd be useful to explain why you feel this is a better approach than the accepted answer. What does Aptitude provide that the earlier answers were lacking? Why should readers implement your approach?

Comment: Am I the only one who thought this is answering how to do the opposite of what the question is asking?