# apt-get install npm Errors

Tags: node.js

When i type the command apt-get install npm i get this error

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 npm : Depends: nodejs but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-abbrev (>= 1.0.4) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-ansi but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-archy but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-block-stream but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-fstream (>= 0.1.22) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-fstream-ignore but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-github-url-from-git but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-glob (>= 3.1.21) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-graceful-fs (>= 2.0.0) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-inherits but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-ini (>= 1.1.0) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-lockfile but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-lru-cache (>= 2.3.0) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-minimatch (>= 0.2.11) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-mkdirp (>= 0.3.3) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-gyp (>= 0.10.9) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-nopt (>= 2.1.1) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-npmlog but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-once but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-osenv but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-read but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-read-package-json (>= 1.1.0) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-request (>= 2.25.0) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-retry but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-rimraf (>= 2.2.2) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-semver (>= 2.1.0) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-sha but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-slide but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-tar (>= 0.1.18) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-which but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

is there any way i could fix this?

Comment: To be a bit cheeky, did you read the error? "The following packages have unmet dependencies: npm : Depends: nodejs"

Comment: yeah, i read it but i dont really know what it means im very new

Answer (score 0):

Install node.js [because](https://www.npmjs.com/get-npm). apt install nodejs

Comment: i tried it just says 
nodejs is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

Comment: Then you should have npm installed. What is the output of "npm -v"?

Comment: the output is 4.5.0

Comment: ok so then the error is normal? because a thing still dosent seem to be working but it might not be because of node.js then

Comment: Well you should not get the errors that is for sure. it should say that you already have npm at it's latest version for your distro. You could try to re install nodejs to see if the errors dissapear [help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32426601/completly-uninstall-nodejs-npm-and-node-in-ubuntu-14-04)

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you that what you are trying to install is reliant on NodeJS but it is not installed and it won't be installed.

You can see if you actually have it installed by typing node -v into the command line, this should show you what version you have.

You can download and install it from their site [here](https://nodejs.org).

Comment: I would advise uninstalling your current node and reinstalling then, I can see from other comments you say you have version 4.5 but the latest version is 7.10.0.