# npm install error `not foundram Files/nodejs/npm: 3: /mnt/c/Program Files/nodejs/npm:`

Tags: npm-install

I have installed Ubuntu Bash on Windows. I already have `nodejs` and `npm` on my windows machine at `C:\Program Files\nodejs`. In the bash shell in Windows, I am running a script which uses `npm install` command. The script is giving following error

```
: not foundram Files/nodejs/npm: 3: /mnt/c/Program Files/nodejs/npm:
: not foundram Files/nodejs/npm: 5: /mnt/c/Program Files/nodejs/npm:
/mnt/c/Program Files/nodejs/npm: 6: /mnt/c/Program Files/nodejs/npm: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting "in")
```

Comment: I got this even after installing nodejs in Ubuntu on Windows, the solution is to restart the bash shell.

Answer (score 156, accepted):

**Note:** Before following the steps below, first try to restart your shell.

You can install Node.js and NPM with your Windows PowerShell as well, so if you've done that it won't work properly for your Subsystem. That means you have to install it twice (Powershell and Subsystem) or decide on one thing.

If the preceding text, has not helped you, this is how to solve the problem:

Remove your current installations

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove node
("sudo apt autoremove node" if console is asking for it)
sudo apt-get --purge remove nodejs
```

Install node the right way.
This is for version 14 ([view current LTS version](https://nodejs.org/en/)):

```
curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_14.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

Then install build tools so you can install add-ons for npm later

```
sudo apt-get install -y build-essential
```

Now you can type in

```
npm -v
node -v
Same thing: nodejs -v
```

to check whether Node.js and NPM are installed correctly. If it shows nothing, **restart the shell.**
If it still shows the same error, **restart the WSL/ PC or try with `sudo npm -v`**

Here are two links that may also help you.
https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/#debian-and-ubuntu-based-linux-distributions
https://github.com/nodesource/distributions/blob/master/README.md#debinstall

Also, take a look at the [Node Version Manager (NVM)](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm). With it, you can easily switch back and forth between versions.

Comment: As per Rosdi's comment above, following these steps and THEN restarting the Ubuntu Bash Shell worked for me.

Comment: `sudo apt install note` or `node`? Anyway, still failing

Answer (score 41):

The solution provided by **phucanhapril** on May 24, 2017 in [this thread](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/1512) worked for me.

To summarise, edit ~/.profile and change your PATH to this:

```
PATH="$HOME/bin:$HOME/.local/bin:/usr/bin:$PATH"
```

(By default it does not include /usr/bin)

Then run:

```
source ~/.profile
```

I am not quite sure why npm doesn't work properly in the first place, or why /usr/bin isn't in PATH by default, but the solution worked for me.

Answer (score 17):

I had the same problem to solve I installed "NVM" in my Subsystem

Follow these steps and see if it will solve for you:

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install build-essential libssl-dev

curl -sL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.31.0/install.sh -o install_nvm.sh

bash install_nvm.sh

source ~/.profile

nvm install 11.13.0
```

Answer (score 8):

You can try `sudo npm install` it was a solution in my particular case.

Comment: That should be avoided, since now you are installing things as root. You should only be installing things as current user, unless you have a good reason to install as the root user.

Answer (score 5):

Linux command for install `nodejs` and `npm`

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs
sudo apt-get install npm
```

Set path in linux

```
export PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

reference
https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/3882

Answer (score 4):

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

this is enough, if you still face the problem

node installation needs restart, close you ubuntu window and start again it will solve your problem :)

Answer (score 3):

On Visual Studio -> Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> Web Package Management -> make sure `$(PATH)` is above all the rest.

As long it is not located at the top of the list VS will try to use VS tools instead of npm.

You should also refer windows to the current npm version by following this screenshot, after try `npm --version`.

Changing npm path:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. This is what I did.

**Step 1.** Type `node -v` and `npm -v` commands in Windows PowerShell and check if node and npm are properly installed

**Step 2.** Add this to the  `~/.zshrc` or  `~/.bashrc` file

```
export NVM_DIR="$([ -z "${XDG_CONFIG_HOME-}" ] && printf %s "${HOME}/.nvm" || printf %s "${XDG_CONFIG_HOME}/nvm")"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"
```

**Step 3.** Type `source ~/.zshrc` and/or  `source ~/.bashrc`

**Step 4.** Type `node -v` and `npm -v` commands in `bash` or `zsh` shells and the correct versions should now appear

Comment: Can you explain what the 2nd step does?

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue in both Debian and Ubuntu (though in Ubuntu the `nvm` command did work) when I was running Windows 10 version 1703. Then when I upgraded to version 1903 the problem disappeared.

Comment: None of the rest worked for npm, but this did, although it took at hot minute to get nvm installed.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error and it may seem silly, but I fixed it by simply typing `exit` in the console and opening it again.

Answer (score 1):

I received this error when I modified my "~/.bashrc" file to shorten up the bash directory.

At first I had:

```
if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
            PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\W\[\033[00m\]\$ '
    else
                PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u\h:\W\$'
        fi
```

....But then could not run any node operation. I rolled it back and the error stopped happening.

After some troubleshooting, I was able to fix the error by adding `~` before the `$` on `PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u\h:\W\~$`

Answer (score 1):

I just read through many threads trying to do this.  There is complete documentation for setting up node, nvm, and npm  in wsl,  here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/nodejs/setup-on-wsl2

If you already installed node and npm using the following commands,

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs
sudo apt-get install npm
```

NPM will not work. You must first uninstall them using:

```
sudo apt-get remove nodejs
sudo apt-get remove npm
```

Follow the guide to completely uninstalling here: [How can I completely uninstall nodejs, npm and node in Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32426601/how-can-i-completely-uninstall-nodejs-npm-and-node-in-ubuntu-14-04)

Then reinstall from the windows guide referenced above.
The windows guide has many other useful resources.

The Tldr to install(from Microsoft Docs):

```
sudo apt-get install curl

curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.37.2/install.sh | bash

nvm install --lts
```

Answer (score 0):

I had identical output to that in the question. It occurs because Ubuntu on WSL adds Windows paths to the bash shell, but of course the Windows executables do not work in bash.

I installed nvm, and from there installed node into bash. NVM works out all the paths so it works.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/1640#issuecomment-616887435

```
# sudo vi /etc/wsl.conf
[interop]
appendWindowsPath = false
```