# Cannot find module 'node-v46-linux-x64/node_sqlite3.node' error in laravel-echo-server

Tags: node.js, laravel, sqlite, laravel-echo

I have to set [laravel-echo-server](https://github.com/tlaverdure/laravel-echo-server) in my laravel project. I have successfully installed it and it is running perfectly while I'm running from terminal. But while running from supervisor, it throws error

> Cannot find module 'node-v46-linux-x64/node_sqlite3.node'

I have almost spend two days to solve this issue. But I didn't get success. So if anyone know the answer, it will be appreciated.

Here are all step/configuration details.

1. Install node 7.10.0 (https://github.com/nodejs/help/wiki/Installation)
2. Install laravel-echo-server globally and initialise it in my project

After these steps, if I run 'laravel-echo-server start' from terminal, it gets run perfectly.

Now I have to set this command in supervisor. So i have performed these steps.

1. create symlink of laravel-echo-server (`sudo ln -s /usr/lib/nodejs/node-v7.10.0/lib/node_modules/laravel-echo-server/bin/server.js /usr/bin/laravel-echo-server`)
2. set 'laravel-echo-server start' command in supervisor

   Here are supervisor details.

   File location: `/etc/supervisor/conf.d/laravel.conf`

   ```
   [program:laravel-echo-server]
   command=/usr/bin/laravel-echo-server start --dir=/var/www/html/laravel
   autostart=true
   autorestart=true
   stderr_logfile=/var/www/html/laravel/laravel-echo-server-err.log
   stdout_logfile=/var/www/html/laravel/laravel-echo-server-out.log
   ```
3. Run `sudo supervisorctl reread` and `sudo supervisorctl update`
4. Run `sudo supervisorctl start laravel-echo-server`

But it throws error. Here is error log.

```
Error: Cannot find module '/usr/lib/nodejs/node-v7.10.0/lib/node_modules/laravel-echo-server/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/node-v46-linux-x64/node_sqlite3.node'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:326:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:277:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:354:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/nodejs/node-v7.10.0/lib/node_modules/laravel-echo-server/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/sqlite3.js:4:15)
    at Module._compile (module.js:410:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:354:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/nodejs/node-v7.10.0/lib/node_modules/laravel-echo-server/dist/database/sqlite.js:3:15)
    at Module._compile (module.js:410:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
```

There is `node-v51-linux-x64` directory in `/usr/lib/nodejs/node-v7.10.0/lib/node_modules/laravel-echo-server/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding`.

Comment: try `npm install sqlite3 --build-from-source`

Comment: or just rename v51 to v46

Comment: @SapneshNaik renaming is not working

Comment: @SapneshNaik can you please tell me that from where I should run `npm install sqlite3 --build-from-source`? FYI, laravel-echo-server runs `sqlite3@3.1.13 install` itself while installing laravel-echo-server. See [https://prnt.sc/hknskn](https://prnt.sc/hknskn)

Comment: Run it from your laravel folder

Comment: @SapneshNaik still same issue. laravel-echo-server is looking in `/usr/lib/nodejs/node-v7.10.0/lib/node_modules/laravel-echo-server/node_modules`, not in my project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I have fixed this issue. I have followed this steps.

1. [Completly uninstall nodejs, npm and node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32426601/completly-uninstall-nodejs-npm-and-node-in-ubuntu-14-04)
2. [Installing Node.js via package manager](https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/)

I have run this commands in step 2.

1. `curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_7.x | sudo -E bash -`
2. `sudo apt-get install -y nodejs`
3. `sudo apt-get install -y build-essential`

Then I have installed laravel-echo-server. And everything works fine for me. But if you get permission error, you should run `sudo chown -R $USER /usr/lib/node_modules`. and run `sudo ln -sfn ../lib/node_modules/laravel-echo-server/bin/server.js /usr/bin/laravel-echo-server` in case of symlink error.