# Unable to uninstall node from ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: node.js, node-modules

I tried these two commands to uninstall node js but I am not able to do it.

```
sudo apt-get purge nodejs
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

when I check for version, it shows

```
v9.3.0
```

And I want to install node 8.x

Comment: what is the output of those commands?

Comment: also check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32426601/completly-uninstall-nodejs-npm-and-node-in-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: it's showing as Successfully uninstalled message.

Answer (score 2):

I got the same problem.

Step 1: Find the node location using

```
rails@rails-All-Series:~$ whereis node
node: /usr/local/bin/node
```

Step2: Remove node module from these the location.

```
rails@rails-All-Series:/usr/local/bin$sudo rm -rf node
```

Answer (score -1):

Below mentioned link specifies how to delete node package from [ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/786015/how-to-remove-nodejs-from-ubuntu-16-04)

```
sudo apt-get purge nodejs
```

it will only be purging related nodejs packages

Other Alternative will be:

```
 sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove nodejs
```

it will be implementing the below mentioned commands internally:

```
 sudo apt-get purge nodejs
 sudo apt-get autoremove
```

autoremove will actually be removing the related package and they were installed as a dependency module .

Comment: Now you just plagiarized the answer. Copy-Pasting is not the solution.