# How to fix issues with npm?

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I am having a lot of trouble using `npm`. Almost at each install I get issues

```
npm ERR! Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

or

```
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! foobar@1.0.0 lint: `eslint --ext .js,.vue src test/unit test/e2e/specs "--fix"`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the foobar@1.0.0 lint script.
```

or

```
$ sudo npm install -g hpack.js
npm ERR! path /usr/lib/node_modules/.staging/hpack.js-6a009775
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied,
```

or

```
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/usr/lib/node_modules/vue-cli/node_modules/download-git-repo' -> '/usr/lib/node_modules/vue-cli/node_modules/.download-git-repo.DELETE'
```

or

```
$ npm run dev

> foobar@1.0.0 dev /home/ycr/my-project
> webpack-dev-server --inline --progress --config build/webpack.dev.conf.js

sh: 1: webpack-dev-server: not found
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
```

Often I can solve the problem by uninstalling and reinstalling the package or simply manually installing the missing dependencies, but it is painful.

```
sudo npm uninstall -g vue-cli
sudo npm install -g vue-cli
```

But it looks very unstable and I don't understand why I get all these issues.

```
$ node -v
v8.10.0
$ npm -v
5.7.1
$ uname -a
Linux CE589UT 4.4.0-43-Microsoft #1-Microsoft Wed Dec 31 14:42:53 PST 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

My goal is to be able to install packages such as Angular, vue.js, node-red, ... to test them. Until now each time I have to use `npm` I get errors.

Any clues or ideas to troubleshot these instabilities?

Comment: Try installing [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) first, then node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like all the `npm-errors` were redirected to your instance :) which I had faced earlier. It's good to clean your hands on these general errors which make your `npm` handling skills more clear and sharpen.

From the error logs you provided, these type of issue only occurs due to cache junk, broken node installation or permission access to perform `npm` operations.

The global solution I would suggest you, to overcome all these issues. use `NVM` to work around `node` and `npm`. `NVM` stands for node version manager which itself handles all the required `node-path` structure, permissions to respective directories, and all the `node` and `npm` versions compatibility. Below is the link to install `NVM` on your system.

https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/how-to-install-node-js-via-nvm-node-version-manager-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts/

Before using `NVM` i will recommend you to uninstall/remove `node` and `npm` completely from your system. to do this you can refer below links:

https://hungred.com/how-to/completely-removing-nodejs-npm/

[Completly uninstall nodejs, npm and node in ubuntu 14.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32426601/completly-uninstall-nodejs-npm-and-node-in-ubuntu-14-04)

Hope this will help you!