# Gulp installation error on Laravel in Ubuntu

Tags: laravel, ubuntu, laravel-5, gulp, ubuntu-16.04

I run `npm install gulp` in Ubuntu. Show this error:

My Server is Ubuntu 16.04.

Framework is Laravel 5.6.

```
ERROR: npm is known not to run on Node.js v4.2.6
Node.js 4 is supported but the specific version you're running has
a bug known to break npm. Please update to at least 4.7.0 to use this
version of npm. You can find the latest release of Node.js at https://nodejs.org/
```

I run `node -v` show this message: `v4.2.6`

I run `sudo apt-get install --only-upgrade nodejs` show this message:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
nodejs is already the newest version (9.11.1-1nodesource1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: What part of the message is unclear?

Comment: That's a really old node version. Get the [latest here](https://nodejs.org/en/download/)

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt , What should i do? I install nodejs version 9 but show this error!

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt , What should i do? I install nodejs version 9 but show this error!

Comment: @DigitalDrifter , I install version 9, But show this error !

Comment: You still have version 4.2.6 installed and npm i using it. Remove it from the system.

Comment: After run install nodejs show this message: `nodejs is already the newest version (9.11.1-1nodesource1).`

Comment: @DigitalDrifter I update my question

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I update my question

Comment: What does `which node` give as output? I suspect you installed another node.js version outside of the package management.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt How to issue this problem?

Comment: Uninstall the wrong one.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I run `sudo apt-get purge nodejs` after remove nodejs i run `node -v` show `4.2.6` version :-(

Comment: You just learned something: Don't install software without the use of the package manager. How to fix that? Remove the stuff manually.

Comment: Did you follow the instructions at https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/#debian-and-ubuntu-based-linux-distributions ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this.. First, Uninstall completely nodejs and npm.

```
sudo apt remove nodejs npm
```

Then, reinstall it:

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_9.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

Refer: https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/#debian-and-ubuntu-based-linux-distributions

Comment: Hi, I remove `nodejs` but after run `node -v` show `4.2.6` !!! How to remove this version?

Comment: Your node is not completely removed. Try this answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32426601/completly-uninstall-nodejs-npm-and-node-in-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: Afetr run `sudo apt-get remove nodejs`, i run `node -v` show this message: `4.2.6`. !!!!! How to remove version 4.2.6 !!!?

Comment: The best way to manage node version is nvm(Node Version Manager). Install nvm from official nvm repository: https://github.com/creationix/nvm
Then run this commands to update: https://gist.github.com/frenchbread/d70cb4529073f5196faf7bd2e0464fb5

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install nodejs (you already have node so this step is probably not required) 
sudo npm install -g gulp
```

That should resolve your issue.

Comment: I install nodejs version 9, But show this error. after run insta;; nodejs show this message : `nodejs is already the newest version (9.11.1-1nodesource1).`