# Error while installing Hyperledger Composer

Tags: node.js, npm, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I am getting the same errors again and again. I tried installing different npm versions and even updated my Ubuntu to 18.04, to no avail.
The command I used for installing was

`npm install -g composer-cli@0.19`

The errors I am getting are:

> gyp ERR! node -v v11.3.0
>
> gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
>
> gyp ERR! not ok
>
> node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
>
> node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute
>   '/home/akshay/.nvm/versions/node/v11.3.0/bin/node
>   /home/akshay/.nvm/versions/node/v11.3.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js
>   build --fallback-to-build --library=static_library
>   --module=/home/akshay/.nvm/versions/node/v11.3.0/lib/node_modules/composer-cli/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v67-linux-x64-glibc/grpc_node.node
>   --module_name=grpc_node --module_path=/home/akshay/.nvm/versions/node/v11.3.0/lib/node_modules/composer-cli/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v67-linux-x64-glibc'
>   (1)
>
> node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.
>   (/home/akshay/.nvm/versions/node/v11.3.0/lib/node_modules/composer-cli/node_modules/grpc/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:83:29)
>
> node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
>
> node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose
>   (internal/child_process.js:978:16)
>
> node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit
>   (internal/child_process.js:265:5)
>
> node-pre-gyp ERR! System Linux 4.15.0-39-generic
>
> node-pre-gyp ERR! command
>   "/home/akshay/.nvm/versions/node/v11.3.0/bin/node"
>   "/home/akshay/.nvm/versions/node/v11.3.0/lib/node_modules/composer-cli/node_modules/grpc/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp"
>   "install" "--fallback-to-build" "--library=static_library"
>
> node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd
>   /home/akshay/.nvm/versions/node/v11.3.0/lib/node_modules/composer-cli/node_modules/grpc
>
> node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v11.3.0
>
> node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.7.0
>
> node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok
>
> Failed to execute '/home/akshay/.nvm/versions/node/v11.3.0/bin/node
>   /home/akshay/.nvm/versions/node/v11.3.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js
>   build --fallback-to-build --library=static_library
>   --module=/home/akshay/.nvm/versions/node/v11.3.0/lib/node_modules/composer-cli/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v67-linux-x64-glibc/grpc_node.node
>   --module_name=grpc_node --module_path=/home/akshay/.nvm/versions/node/v11.3.0/lib/node_modules/composer-cli/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v67-linux-x64-glibc'
>   (1)
>
> CXX(target)
>   Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/backoff/backoff.oe
>
> CXX(target)
>   Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/channel/channel_args.o
>
> CXX(target)
>   Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/channel/channel_stack.o
>
> CXX(target)
>   Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/channel/channel_stack_builder.o
>
> In file included from
>   ../deps/grpc/src/core/lib/channel/channel_stack_builder.h:24:0,
>
> from ../deps/grpc/src/core/lib/channel/channel_stack_builder.cc:19:
>
> ../deps/grpc/src/core/lib/channel/channel_args.h:22:10: fatal error:
>   grpc/compression.h: No such file or directory
>
> compilation terminated.
>
> grpc.target.mk:394: recipe for target
>   'Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/channel/channel_stack_builder.o'
>   failed
>
> make: ***
>   [Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/channel/channel_stack_builder.o]
>   Error 1
>
> make: Leaving directory
>   '/home/akshay/.nvm/versions/node/v11.3.0/lib/node_modules/composer-cli/node_modules/grpc/build'
>
> gyp ERR! build error
>
> gyp ERR! stack Error: make failed with exit code: 2
>
> gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit
>   (/home/akshay/.nvm/versions/node/v11.3.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:262:23)
>    gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
>
> gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit
>   (internal/child_process.js:254:12)
>
> gyp ERR! System Linux 4.15.0-39-generic
>
> gyp ERR! command "/home/akshay/.nvm/versions/node/v11.3.0/bin/node"
>   "/home/akshay/.nvm/versions/node/v11.3.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js"
>   "build" "--fallback-to-build" "--library=static_library"
>   "--module=/home/akshay/.nvm/versions/node/v11.3.0/lib/node_modules/composer-cli/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v67-linux-x64-glibc/grpc_node.node"
>   "--module_name=grpc_node"
>   "--module_path=/home/akshay/.nvm/versions/node/v11.3.0/lib/node_modules/composer-cli/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v67-linux-x64-glibc"
>
> gyp ERR! cwd
>   /home/akshay/.nvm/versions/node/v11.3.0/lib/node_modules/composer-cli/node_modules/grpc
>
> gyp ERR! node -v v11.3.0
>
> gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
>
> gyp ERR! not ok
>
> npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4
>   (node_modules/composer-cli/node_modules/fsevents):
>
> npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform
>   for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current:
>   {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})`
>
> `npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
>
> npm ERR! errno 1
>
> npm ERR! grpc@1.10.1 install: node-pre-gyp install
>   --fallback-to-build --library=static_library
>    npm ERR! Exit status 1
>
> npm ERR!
>
> npm ERR! Failed at the grpc@1.10.1 install script.
>
> npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely
>   additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
>
> npm ERR!
>   /home/akshay/.npm/_logs/2018-11-29T02_27_29_404Z-debug.log

Answer (score 1):

As you are using nvm which is the recommended way to manage node, its easy to switch to a different version of node, issue the following commands

```
nvm install 8

nvm use 8
```

Now install composer as normal.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the node completely of current version and and try to install node 8.x version.

for remove node version refer this:
[remove node completely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32426601/completly-uninstall-nodejs-npm-and-node-in-ubuntu-14-04)

for install node 8.x version:

> `curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | sudo -E bash -`
>
> `sudo apt-get install -y nodejs`

And then try to install `npm install -g composer-cli@0.19`

Comment: Sorry, but this is not the recommended way for people to install node for composer. We explicitly state that node should not be installed using sudo as it makes things more difficult.

Comment: Brother, I just follow instruction from this Linux forum :


  https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-node-js-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux

Comment: @david_k Installing with sudo made things easier for me

Answer (score 0):

Just reinstall npm

```
sudo npm uninstall npm -g
sudo apt update
sudo apt intall npm
```