# Cannot update NodeJS version

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

Installing nodejs doesn't update nodejs version

```
$ nodejs --version
v8.10.0
$ sudo npm install -g nodejs@latest
+ nodejs@0.0.0
updated 1 package in 1.558s

$ nodejs --version
v8.10.0
```

NodeJS path found at

```
$ which nodejs
/usr/bin/nodejs
```

How can I update Nodejs version to latest

Comment: Uninstall the previous version as described here https://stackoverflow.com/a/33947181/3284355 and then follow this to install new version https://github.com/nodesource/distributions#installation-instructions

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use NVM to install any version of nodejs and flexibility to switch between any nodejs version.

Install NVM using (for ubuntu)

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install build-essential libssl-dev

curl -sL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.8/install.sh -o install_nvm.sh
```

To check nvm installed & find available nodejs versions

```
nvm ls-remote
```

Install node

```
nvm install 12.16.1
```

Now nodejs version should show 12.16.1

```
node --version   # 12.16.1
```

More ref can be found [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-node-js-on-ubuntu-16-04)