# npm ERR! cb.apply is not a function

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I am getting this error

```
npm ERR! cb.apply is not a function
```

in Linux while doing `npm install` although my npm version is 6.9.0. My node version is v12.18.3. How to resolve this issue?

Comment: In my case, I had the "start" script run an `npx` command, removing `npx` and installing the dependency I was trying to run with `npx` solved the issue

Answer (score 145):

Would be helpful if you shared if it's Windows or Linux, but the error seems to occur on Windows. [Possible solution](https://github.com/nodejs/help/issues/2874):

```
1. Go to C:\Users(your username)\AppData\Roaming
2. Delete the npm folder (possibly back it up) and if there is one npm cache folder.
3. Run `npm cache clear --force` (--force is now required to clean cache)
```

After that, `npm install` should work fine.

Comment: On my Windows computer, it was `npm cache clean` (not `npm clean cache`).

Comment: I removed the directories but I also had to remove environment variables associated with nodejs and some other resources as well. Just to add to the above solution, make sure "EVERYTHING" nodejs related is wiped out clean from the machine.

Comment: Yeah, this method is correct but at last step you can Run "npm cache clean --force" to clean your cache. and run "npm cache verify" to verify if you successfully done your task.

Answer (score 42):

### Mac/Macbook users

Since this question is fairly active and a top google result for this issue (I know the OP is using Linux), here is how to fix it on a Mac.

On a Mac you do not have the `AppData\Roaming` folder, so simply run `npm root -g` and then navigate to the hidden directory and delete the `node_modules` there. If using `nvm` you'll need to rerun `nvm use x.x.x` (where `x.x.x` is your node version).

Comment: Thanks. My problem was that I needed to run `nvm use x.x.x`

Comment: My hidden directory only has a dtrace folder in it. No node_modules

Comment: ok well. what if we deleted our `npm root -g`?

Comment: This can also happen if npx uses yarn. Find the global yarn node_modules folder using `yarn global dir` then delete the `node_modules`folder in that location.

Answer (score 26):

Solution for Windows:

In my case I didn't want to delete all the npm directory inside `C:/users/me/AppData/Roaming/` because I had many global modules that already existed and installed.

What worked was inspired by @user14360499's answer:

1. go inside `C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules`
2. delete the `npm` dir
3. `npm install` my project, and keep working as usually

Comment: the ultimate solution

Answer (score 17):

Solution for ubuntu 18.04:

```
sudo apt-get remove nodejs
sudo apt-get remove npm
sudo rm /usr/local/bin/node
sudo rm /usr/local/bin/npm
sudo apt-get install nodejs
sudo apt-get install npm
```

Then try node and npm version:

```
node -v
npm -v
```

If it says there is no such node/npm after you already install, then:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/node /usr/local/bin/node
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/npm /usr/local/bin/npm
```

Try this if the command works:

```
npm -v
node -v
```

In case when you want to update npm/node stable version:

```
sudo npm install n -g
sudo n stable
```

Comment: Well, bless your little heart. I was getting the error when doing a `npx create-react-app my-app`, but I accidentally left out the `my-app` part (a serendipitous accident), and suddenly it said I needed to do `create-react-app@5`. At the `OK?` prompt, I typed  "Y". Then, it installed create-react-app (which I didn't know existed). Then I followed your last two lines, `sudo npm install n -g1` and `sudo n stable`. After that, I successfully performed a `npx create-react-app my-app`.

Answer (score 10):

For me, on Centos 7, it was about removing `graceful-ts` used locally by `npx`. First, I've had to open log file which was mentioned in the error message:

```
npm ERR! cb.apply is not a function

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2022-04-04T07_45_27_182Z-debug.log
```

In that log file there was this path:

```
verbose stack     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npx/node_modules/npm/node_modules/graceful-fs/polyfills.js:287:18
```

So I removed whole `graceful-fs` directory and ran npx again. Everything worked.

```
rm -fR /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npx/node_modules/npm/node_modules/graceful-fs
```

Comment: this helped under win 10 with scoop. just delete C:\Users\myuser\scoop\persist\nodejs\bin\node_modules\npx\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs

Answer (score 9):

I had the same issue with Nodist. After changing my Node version, my npm version was actually incompatible with it. So if you're using Nodist, make sure to run `nodist npm {scope} match` after switching Node versions, where scope is either global, local or env.

Answer (score 6):

Had the same error **(macOS Big Sur)** when i tried to use npx.

**How i fixed it (using nvm)**
when i run:

```
nvm ls
```

[nvm ls output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/frhwH.png)

**Fix:**

```
nvm alias default node
nvm install 'lts/*'
```

[nvm install output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d66co.png)

Answer (score 5):

In my case it was indeed the `graceful-fs` package. Running

```
npm i -g --force graceful-fs
```

fixed the issue. I also ran `nodist npm {scope} match` before but I'm unsure if it was neccessary.

Comment: After doing this I needed to run `npm i create-react-app` followed by `npm audit fix --force` then I was able to run `npx create-react-app react-app`

Answer (score 3):

Ciao, this problem could be connected to `graceful-fs` package. You could try to reinstall it:

```
npm install graceful-fs --save-dev
```

Answer (score 3):

On macOS BigSur, I had this problem when executing:

```
npx install-peerdeps --dev eslint-config-airbnb
```

To fix, I ran

```
brew update
```

after which I was prompted to run

```
brew upgrade
```

Running the two commands fixed the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Solution for Ubuntu 18.04=>

1. Visit 'usr/lib/node_modules'.
2. Delete 'n', 'npm','npm-clean','npm-install-peers'. That means delete all the node & npm related folders.
3. Install the npm again.

Answer (score 2):

I have tried a lot of solutions from different posts and google pages and nothing worked for me.

I ended up cleaning all traces of node, nodejs, and npm. May need some manual force remove after the purge call. And then installed using nvm.

https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-node-js-on-ubuntu-20-04/#installing-nodejs-and-npm-using-nvm

And it resolved the issue for me. It got the nodejs v 15.4.0 and the compatible version of npm 7.0.15 ( before using apt-get it was installing npm 6.9.0)

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem while trying to run `npx`.

I found that `nvm` had been removed from the PATH.

I added it back to my .zshrc file and it worked.

Comment: Hi Batch,

It looks like you have both an answer and a question in here. Please, split them. Still, before doing that please see if the same problem was already solved in one of the questions in our community.

Thanks.

Comment: @FarrukhNormuradov what was batch question?

Comment: I do not see any logic in my comment. Maybe the answer was edited afterwards. If not, I will delete my comment.

Comment: Nope, no edit from my side :)

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this error when running `npx sb init`. For some reason, the command worked localy but not in CI. I tried most of the solutions from here. But only the following worked.

I replaced `npx sb init` with `yarn global add @storybook/cli && yarn exec sb init` as suggested here: https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/3937#issuecomment-751289438

(NVM, Node.js 14, Yarn 1)

Comment: error Couldn't find the binary sb

Answer (score 1):

The problem has occured when the node and npm packages are not latest.

For me the problem is resolved when I completely removed npm and node, and made a clean installation.
I am using ubuntu 22 lts

- to remove node and npm completely I have followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60701804/15392115)

Answer (score 0):

Feb 2021 fix:

```
npm install
```

And then commit the changes to `package-lock.json`. That should update all your dependencies, thus fixing this issue.

More info: https://help.heroku.com/ZV7S7D6T/why-is-my-node-build-is-suddenly-displaying-npm-err-cb-apply-is-not-a-function (this happened to me on heroku)

Comment: I had a fresh install of nvm, node and npm on windows.  I tried to run `$ npx create-react-app myApp`   This command totally fixed the issue for me, even though there was no package.json file in the local directory.

Comment: Worked for me almost a year later on windows. I upgraded from v12 node LTS to v16 LTS, then suddenly `npx` stopped working. i tried deleting cache and clearing it, but nothing solved until i ran `npm install`, then boom works like magic

Answer (score 0):

For linux users:

1. **uninstall NPM**, to do it go to **/usr/local/lib/node_modules** and do:

> sudo rm -r n npm npx

2. Once uninstalled, **re-instal** it:

> npm install

3. Even after doing this, in a specific project when trying to install a specific npm package, **you may get** the following error:

> bash: /usr/local/bin/npm: No such file or directory

If so, in the terminal just run:

> hash -r

4. Now you can retry installation of your wanted npm package.

Answer (score 0):

In my case (Mac) it was because I had `npx` installed alongside `n` (alternative to `nvm`).

```
$ which npx
/usr/local/bin/npx
```

I removed this exectutable and now:

```
$ which npx
/Users/MY_USER/n/bin/npx
```

and it works now.

Answer (score 0):

For me , the solution was to delete the node modules and bower components folder of the project.

Answer (score 0):

for the mac OS remove the node version and reinstalling was work for me. I used n npm version manager.

Answer (score 0):

On windows, using `nvm`, i just installed a newer nodejs version (before 14.17.0, now 14.18.2)

Answer (score 0):

So many solutions just made me even more puzzled. I downloaded and installed the newest LTS NodeJS and it worked just fine.
https://nodejs.org/en/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

if you are also getting this error:

```
1 warn npm npm does not support Node.js v16.2.0
```

that means that your npm version is not correct.

reinstall npm, try again.

It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm on a Mac, and had exactly the same issue. Deleting the node modules seemed a little overkill for me, so I ran `npm update` and it solved the issue! Please note I did not yet have any package.json or any modules on the repo I was working in.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10:

When calling npx create-react-app my-app, i got following error:

> npm ERR! cb.apply is not a function

To fix it, i did the following:

> 1. Go to the folder you want to create the app in.
> 2. npm install create-react-app --save-dev
> 3. npx create-react-app my-app

Answer (score 0):

Had this issue when creating a new react app using `create-react-app`.
[image]

I was using nvm, so I just updated it to the latest LTS version:

`nvm install --lts`
[image]

then switched to the newly installed lts version:

`nvm use --lts`
[image]

closed and reopened the terminal, reran `create-react-app` and the error was fixed!

Answer (score 0):

This is a conflict between npm <= 5 and newer versions of Node 12 and 14. The solution is to upgrade npm to >= 6, which is installed with Node 12 and Node 14 by default.

More details are described in this GitHub issue: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/34162#issuecomment-652575905

Take the following steps:

1.Make sure that you're running npm >= 6 on your local machine. (This comes by default with Node 12 and 14.)

2.Run npm install and check in any changes to the package-lock.json.

3.Remove the "npm" key from the "engines" in package.json. The buildpack will simply use the version of npm that comes with your set version of Node. For example, both Node 12.18.3 and 14.6.0 are installed with npm 6.14.6.

Answer (score 0):

## Fixing Issue on Mac

If you're facing a Node.js module problem on your Mac, follow these steps:

1. Open Terminal.
2. Get the global npm modules path with:

   npm root -g
3. Delete the folder with:

   sudo rm -r /usr/local/lib/node_modules
4. Test by installing a package:

   npm install
5. If not fixed, install 'graceful-fs':

   npm install graceful-fs --save-dev

By following these steps, you can resolve the Node.js module issue on your Mac.

Remember: Use terminal commands with caution and understand their effects.
Feel free to copy and paste this concise version into a markdown file for quick reference.

Answer (score 0):

In your package-json  locate this

```
 "engines": {
     "node": ">=14.20.1"
  }
```

And remove it , redeploy  again

Comment: That’s a terrible advice; you should always explicitely define the engine your app supports.

Answer (score 0):

I add exact same issue, so I did my researches. And I found this thread.

Though I searched some more and here is what I found :

From this website https://nodejs.org/en/about/previous-releases

I can say, that the problem comes from npm 6.9.0

You should try to upgrade npm to 6.14.16 and then retry :)

It worked in my case :)

(this answer hsould also be marks as resolved) :D

Answer (score -1):

Solution for ubuntu =>

1. Completely remove nodejs and npm from your system.

```
sudo apt-get remove nodejs
sudo apt-get remove npm
```

2. Install node from this reference (https://computingforgeeks.com/install-node-js-14-on-ubuntu-debian-linux/) - This will inturn install latest npm .

Answer (score -1):

Had the same error was simply in the wrong folder -.- (not a typescript project)