# I have this error message "npm ERR! Linux 5.4.72-microsoft-standard-WSL2" on my terminal when I run "npm install"

Tags: javascript, windows, vue.js, vuetify.js, wsl-2

I have this error message : `npm ERR! Linux 5.4.72-microsoft-standard-WSL2` on my terminal when I run `npm install`. I'm on a vue.js app and I have this message since I installed vuetify.
Here is the whole error message :

```
npm ERR! Linux 5.4.72-microsoft-standard-WSL2
npm ERR! argv "/home/josephine/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.0/bin/node" "/home/josephine/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.0/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v14.15.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! cb.apply is not a function.
```

I also cannot install the latest version of npm I think this is related to the problem. (I have this version `v3.10.10`).
And when I run `npm run serve` I have this :

```
> vue-cli-service serve
sh: 1: vue-cli-service: not found
npm ERR! Linux 5.4.72-microsoft-standard-WSL2
npm ERR! argv "/home/josephine/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.0/bin/node" "/home/josephine/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.0/bin/npm" "run" "serve"
npm ERR! node v14.15.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! my-app@0.1.0 serve: vue-cli-service serve
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the my-app@0.1.0 serve script 'vue-cli-service serve'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the my-app package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     vue-cli-service serve
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs my-app
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls my-app
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to install?`.
```

I have the Vue.JS version `@ vue / cli 4.5.12`.
At last, I have a Window PC and I have installed linux and ubuntu.
I thank you in advance if you can help me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [npm ERR! cb.apply is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63429304/npm-err-cb-apply-is-not-a-function)

Answer (score -1):

Your npm version is outdated. Your version is 3.x but we're currently at 7.x

Run

```
npm update -g
```

and then try again.

Comment: Ok I did that but it doesn't work. I still have the same error message.