# why is npm giving me weird errors?

Tags: node.js, npm, redux

Hi I am really new to learn redux. 
I was keep trying install redux in VSC. 
So I typed command "npm init" first. 
And then I typed "npm i redux".

As a result I got those error messages.

Here is the Error

```
npm ERR! Linux 5.8.0-63-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "i" "redux"
npm ERR! node v14.17.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10

npm ERR! cb.apply is not a function
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/garamsong/portfolio/practice_redux/redux_first/npm-debug.log
```

I checked my node version and npm version as well

node is v14.17.0 
npm is v3.10.10

I thought It could be my npm version problem, so I tried delete npm.. but it didn't work..

so my question is

1. is it version of npm problem?
2. if not, what is the problem?
3. and how to install redux?

Thanks for reading my stupid question.. but this made me really frustrated..(btw sudo doesn't work at all)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63429304/npm-err-cb-apply-is-not-a-function https://github.com/nodejs/help/issues/2874 use google next time :)

Comment: That aside, you usually should not directly install `redux` nowadays. Use the official Redux toolkit instead. If your tutorial shows you installing `redux`, it is most likely outdated by years.
Best follow the official Redux tutorial at https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-1-overview-concepts

Comment: @Mr.P Thank you so much! I will do from the next time!

Comment: @phry Thank you so much I'll check that right away :)