# npm install gives '.' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. error

Tags: npm, installation, node-modules, grpc

I'm trying to run an existing project, but I'm stuck at install phase.
npm install gives me the following error:

```
npm ERR! path C:\Users\~\Source\node_modules\firebase\node_modules\grpc
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c ./node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library
npm ERR! '.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
npm ERR! operable program or batch file.
```

What could be causing the problem?

I already tried the following commands/workarounds, but this gives me the same error:

npm install --build-from-source @grpc/grpc-js

npm install --build-from-resources

deleting package-lock.json

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with incompatible versions of node and npm between global instalation and your project angular version. To repair it, first you have to download and install nvm from [here](https://content.breatheco.de/en/how-to/nvm-install-windows). Then you type
`nvm install v8.11.3` and
`nvm use v8.11.3`.
After that you have to downgrade npm by typing
`npm i npm@6.3.0 -g`.
Now you can install node modules by typing
`npm i`

But this is not over :) You can't run the project by `ng serve`, because your node and npm version is mismatched with global @angular/cli version. So you have to revert to newest node by typing
`nvm use 14.15.1` (if 14.15.1 is your version of node)
What about npm? It won't upgrade via `npm i npm@latest -g`, you have to use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63429304/npm-err-cb-apply-is-not-a-function) workaround. After that you may have to install angular globally once again by typing
`npm install -g @angular/cli@latest`
and if you did that all and prayed enough, maybe it will work...