# I am getting npm error while installing the React.js in my Visual Studio code editor

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, react-fullstack

I am using node.js (16nth version) in my Visual Studio code Editor. But while installing the react.js I am getting error

I tried in many ways like I installed different versions of node.js . But Every time I am getting same error. So Please help with this issue.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/yUOEs.png)

Comment: Someone has answered a similar query:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/63430285/20009581

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have correctly installed the latest version of Node.js on your system.

Make sure that you are running the latest version of create-react-app by running the command:

```
npm install -g create-react-app
```

Try deleting the node_modules directory and running npm install again to reinstall all the dependencies.

If the issue persists, try running npm cache clean --force to clear the npm cache, and then try running npm install again.

Check if there are any errors in your code by inspecting the browser console or the terminal output.you can share more about the error details here