# NVM can not install nodejs on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: node.js, nvm

I Tried to install nodejs using nvm on ubuntu 18.04. But everytime it's throwing following error stack

```
pasindu@pasindu-HP-EliteBook-850-G7-Notebook-PC:~$ nvm install 0.10.35

Downloading and installing node v0.10.35...
Downloading https://nodejs.org/dist/v0.10.35/node-v0.10.35-linux-x64.tar.gz...
Warning: Failed to create the file                                             
Warning: /home/pasindu/.nvm/.cache/bin/node-v0.10.35-linux-x64/node-v0.10.35-li
Warning: nux-x64.tar.gz: Permission denied
curl: (23) Failure writing output to destination

Binary download from https://nodejs.org/dist/v0.10.35/node-v0.10.35-linux-x64.tar.gz failed, trying source.
grep: /home/pasindu/.nvm/.cache/bin/node-v0.10.35-linux-x64/node-v0.10.35-linux-x64.tar.gz: No such file or directory
Provided file to checksum does not exist.
Binary download failed, trying source.
Detected that you have 12 CPU core(s)
Running with 11 threads to speed up the build
Downloading https://nodejs.org/dist/v0.10.35/node-v0.10.35.tar.gz...
Warning: Failed to create the file                                             
Warning: /home/pasindu/.nvm/.cache/src/node-v0.10.35/node-v0.10.35.tar.gz: 
Warning: Permission denied
curl: (23) Failure writing output to destination

Binary download from https://nodejs.org/dist/v0.10.35/node-v0.10.35.tar.gz failed, trying source.
grep: /home/pasindu/.nvm/.cache/src/node-v0.10.35/node-v0.10.35.tar.gz: No such file or directory
Provided file to checksum does not exist.
```

Comment: There could be chances that, you have installed nvm using sudo.
And now you are trying to install node using nvm without sudo

Comment: I tried by installing nvm on both root and user ends. But still having same error. Then I installed nodeJS using archive.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It may be the problem of snap curl, see [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/snapcraft/+bug/1928185), cos I installed curl with snap at first and always encounter this problem, then I removed curl with `sudo snap remove curl` and reinstall it with `sudo apt install curl`, my current `curl` version is `7.68.0`. then solved it.

Comment: Just ran into this on Ubuntu 20.04. Can confirm that this answer fixed the issue on 20.04 as well.

Comment: This solution also works on 22.04.

Comment: Correct solution vs other threads that wasted my time. This is frustrating that Ubuntu had many ways to do things and creates a ton of ways things can get so wrong

Answer (score 0):

I had to clear the cache:
`nvm cache clear`.

I've got the error after I tried to install a version of Node, which I've tried to install already, however the installation processs failed at the first time due disconnecting from the internet.

Comment: Try this one with Option 3 — Installing Node Using the Node Version Manager
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-node-js-on-ubuntu-20-04