# Just installed nodejs and npm, but sill getting this error in coc. And im windows wsl (Ubuntu)

Tags: node.js, intellisense, vim-plugin, neovim

Got this error in nvim, for neoclide coc. just installed nodejs and npm, still getting this error, it says incompatible node version, and I'm on a Windows WSL ubuntu

```
**[coc.nvim]: /home/helloagrock/.vim/plugged/coc.nvim/build/index.js:7
    throw new Error('coc.nvim requires node >= v12.12.0, current version: ' + v)
    ^
Error: coc.nvim requires node >= v12.12.0, current version: v10.19.0
    at /home/helloagrock/.vim/plugged/coc.nvim/build/index.js:7:11
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/helloagrock/.vim/plugged/coc.nvim/build/index.js:9:3)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:623:3)**
```

Comment: Can you provide node -v command result?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you remove all installed versions of node.js.
Then the best is to install nvm: https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm

With nvm you can install multiple versions of node.js and switch between them.

Comment: hey how to remove it in wsl?

Comment: I don't know WSL, but check this post it explain how to remove node manually https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32426601/how-can-i-completely-uninstall-nodejs-npm-and-node-in-ubuntu