# NPM error installing Gulp: Error: ENOENT, lstat

Tags: npm, gulp

I'm running:

- Ubuntu 14.04
- Node v0.10.25
- NPM v 1.3

Installed NPM via apt-get install. The moment I try to install Gulp (see command in code snippet) I get these failures. I already tried to do 'npm cache clean', adding .npmignore file and adding package.json file. Nothing worked so far.

Any ideas?

```html
sudo npm install gulp gulp-sass gulp-autoprefixer --save-dev

> v8flags@1.0.8 install /home/me/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/v8flags
> node fetch.js

sh: 1: node: not found
npm WARN This failure might be due to the use of legacy binary "node"
npm WARN For further explanations, please read
/usr/share/doc/nodejs/README.Debian
 
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/once/-/once-1.3.1.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/once/-/once-1.3.1.tgz
npm ERR! weird error 127
npm ERR! tar pack Error reading /home/me/tmp/npm-9540-2Uzl7SBx/1422536234106-0.37079049041494727/package
npm ERR! addLocalDirectory Could not pack "/home/me/tmp/npm-9540-2Uzl7SBx/1422536234106-0.37079049041494727/package" to "/home/me/.npm/readable-stream/1.0.33/package.tgz"
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, lstat '/home/me/tmp/npm-9540-2Uzl7SBx/1422536233976-0.40873615234158933/package/test/source-map/util.js'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Linux 3.13.0-37-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "gulp" "gulp-sass" "gulp-autoprefixer" "--save-dev"
npm ERR! cwd /home/me
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.25
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.10
npm ERR! path /home/me/tmp/npm-9540-2Uzl7SBx/1422536233976-0.40873615234158933/package/test/source-map/util.js
npm ERR! fstream_path /home/me/tmp/npm-9540-2Uzl7SBx/1422536233976-0.40873615234158933/package/test/source-map/util.js
npm ERR! fstream_type File
npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! fstream_stack /usr/lib/nodejs/fstream/lib/writer.js:284:26
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, lstat '/home/me/node_modules/gulp-autoprefixer/node_modules/autoprefixer-core/lib/hacks/border-radius.js'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Linux 3.13.0-37-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "gulp" "gulp-sass" "gulp-autoprefixer" "--save-dev"
npm ERR! cwd /home/me
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.25
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.10
npm ERR! path /home/me/node_modules/gulp-autoprefixer/node_modules/autoprefixer-core/lib/hacks/border-radius.js
npm ERR! fstream_path /home/me/node_modules/gulp-autoprefixer/node_modules/autoprefixer-core/lib/hacks/border-radius.js
npm ERR! fstream_type File
npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! fstream_stack /usr/lib/nodejs/fstream/lib/writer.js:284:26
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, lstat '/home/me/node_modules/gulp-autoprefixer/node_modules/gulp-util/node_modules/minimist/index.js'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Linux 3.13.0-37-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "gulp" "gulp-sass" "gulp-autoprefixer" "--save-dev"
npm ERR! cwd /home/me
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.25
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.10
npm ERR! path /home/me/node_modules/gulp-autoprefixer/node_modules/gulp-util/node_modules/minimist/index.js
npm ERR! fstream_path /home/me/node_modules/gulp-autoprefixer/node_modules/gulp-util/node_modules/minimist/index.js
npm ERR! fstream_type File
npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! fstream_stack /usr/lib/nodejs/fstream/lib/writer.js:284:26
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, lstat '/home/me/node_modules/gulp-autoprefixer/node_modules/gulp-util/node_modules/chalk/readme.md'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Linux 3.13.0-37-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "gulp" "gulp-sass" "gulp-autoprefixer" "--save-dev"
npm ERR! cwd /home/me
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.25
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.10
npm ERR! path /home/me/node_modules/gulp-autoprefixer/node_modules/gulp-util/node_modules/chalk/readme.md
npm ERR! fstream_path /home/me/node_modules/gulp-autoprefixer/node_modules/gulp-util/node_modules/chalk/readme.md
npm ERR! fstream_type File
npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! fstream_stack /usr/lib/nodejs/fstream/lib/writer.js:284:26
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)

npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, lstat '/home/me/tmp/npm-9540-2Uzl7SBx/1422536229635-0.048849787563085556/package/test/fixtures/spec/benchmarks/large_empty.scss'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Linux 3.13.0-37-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "gulp" "gulp-sass" "gulp-autoprefixer" "--save-dev"
npm ERR! cwd /home/me
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.25
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.10
npm ERR! path /home/me/tmp/npm-9540-2Uzl7SBx/1422536229635-0.048849787563085556/package/test/fixtures/spec/benchmarks/large_empty.scss
npm ERR! fstream_path /home/me/tmp/npm-9540-2Uzl7SBx/1422536229635-0.048849787563085556/package/test/fixtures/spec/benchmarks/large_empty.scss
npm ERR! fstream_type File
npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! fstream_stack /usr/lib/nodejs/fstream/lib/writer.js:284:26
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/me/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Solved it. Apparently, you need the nodejs-legacy package. Once I installed it through apt-get all errors were fixed at once. I found [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21168141/can-not-install-packages-using-node-package-manager-in-ubuntu) explaining why there is node and nodejs-legacy for anyone who is interested.