# "npm start" gives error in ghost (node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, ghost-blog

I tried to setup ghost after installing node.js but as I run the install for ghost as

```
npm install --productions
```

It gives me the following error

```
> ghost@0.5.10 start /home/kedarkhetia/Downloads/ghost-0.5.10
> node index


module.js:340
    throw err;
    ^
Error: Cannot find module 'streamsearch'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/kedarkhetia/Downloads/ghost-0.5.10/node_modules/busboy/node_modules/dicer/lib/Dicer.js:5:20)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
npm ERR! weird error 8
npm WARN This failure might be due to the use of legacy binary "node"
npm WARN For further explanations, please read
/usr/share/doc/nodejs/README.Debian

npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try running

```
npm install streamsearch
```

Does this work?

This may be related:

[Cannot install packages using node package manager in Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21168141/can-not-install-packages-using-node-package-manager-in-ubuntu/21168305#21168305)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have installed streamsearch.

```
npm install streamsearch
```

If it is still not working, check that you have cloned [stable](http://git@github.com:TryGhost/Ghost.git) for production or not. If you did, re-clone it and do installation steps again. Use `sudo` for npm/grunt commands (if you are on OSX or Linux) for `npm ERR!`.

Answer (score 1):

I just looked at the Ghost Docs, and it says to install the dependencies for production you must run `npm install --production` and not `npm install --productions`. Once you install `streamsearch`, it will keep complaining until you have installed all the individual dependencies with `npm install --production`.

Hope this helps!