# $ babel and $ babel-node don't launch the REPL

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, babeljs

I'm trying to setup babel on Ubuntu 14.04 but it doesn't seem to be working!

Here are some outputs that may be required:

```
$ which node
/usr/sbin/node
$ which nodejs
/usr/bin/nodejs
$ which babel
/usr/local/bin/babel
$ which babel-node
/usr/local/bin/babel-node
```

When I execute `babel` or `babel-node` the prompt just returns. The same happens on executing the commands with a filename as argument. (The file has just `console.log("hello")`.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `/usr/sbin/node` vs `/usr/bin/nodejs` issue has been covered in [Cannot install packages using node package manager in Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21168141/can-not-install-packages-using-node-package-manager-in-ubuntu) but basically Ubuntu has a separate `node` package that is NOT Node.js. The package for Node.js on Ubuntu is called `nodejs`. If you have both installed, it means your scripts will try to run using the other unrelated application. One option is to symlink `nodejs` to `node`.

The best solution however would be to use something like [`nvm`](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) to install node for your user without installing it globally. Then you can install and update node versions extremely easily, and your PATH will always reference `node` properly.

Answer (score 0):

Changing `node` to `nodejs` in the first line of `/usr/local/bin/babel-node` and `/usr/local/bin/babel` solves it.

Comment: Changing the globally installed scripts is not a good idea. If you're not actually using `/usr/sbin/node` remove it and symlink it to `nodejs` so it affects all scripts. Or use `nvm` and install node for your user.

Comment: @loganfsmyth - I didn't know about nvm. Thanks for mentioning it! Could you please turn your comment into an answer?