# babel.js produces no output

Tags: node.js, npm, babeljs

It's installed (`$ sudo npm install babel`), running `$ babel` produces nothing (implying that bash can find something) but `$ babel foo.js` produces no output, and the various babel commands for it to output files are similarly ignored.

Comment: Re-writing my old comment because I posted the wrong link. `babel.js` is not the name of the module, so that npm install should fail. Does node itself work? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32297352/babel-and-babel-node-dont-launch-the-repl

Comment: Note that the package ["Babel" (`npm install babel`)](https://www.npmjs.com/package/Babel) is a different package than the popular [babel.js](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-cli) (maybe I'm repeating what @loganfsmyth said here)

Answer (score 0):

When I run `babel` with no command it waits for input from stdin and closes with control-C.

You might try using `npm install --global babel`.

And make sure there is some js in `foo.js`.  Then `babel foo.js` should output the transformed code.

To check babel version use `babel --version`.

One thing that happened to me is that I put a babel command in `package.json` under `scripts` as `build`, then I ran `npm build` and saw no output confusingly. `npm run build` works though.

Comment: Huh, babel --version also produces no output.

Comment: `sudo npm i -g babel;which babel;ls -lah $(which babel);env;cat /proc/version;babel --version;npm i -g babel;which babel;babel --version`