# Deploy Webpack Angular 2 App

Tags: linux, ubuntu, angular, webpack

I'm trying to deploy an Angular 2 app on Ubuntu and I am getting this error when I run `npm start`

```
> webpack-dev-server --inline --progress --port 8080

npm ERR! weird error 1
npm WARN This failure might be due to the use of legacy binary "node"
npm WARN For further explanations, please read
/usr/share/doc/nodejs/README.Debian

npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

not only this but i can't find documentation anywhere on how to deploy an angular 2 app with webpack, not even on Angular.io

The code I am trying to deploy can be found here: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/webpack.html

Any Help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21168141/cannot-install-packages-using-node-package-manager-in-ubuntu) of stackoverflow duplicate of this i think

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs-legacy
```