# Empty output with forever for nodejs

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, forever

I have a nodeJS server that I want to run forever.

I found this package https://github.com/foreverjs/forever

I installed it using this command line `sudo npm install forever -g`

But when I test it, there is no output (even not for help).

[image]

What it can be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you installed on Ubuntu through apt package manager you need to create a symbolic link since npm modules try to run via /usr/bin/node

```
sudo ln -s `which nodejs` /usr/bin/node
```

or automatically via apt

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs-legacy
```

Comment: I did this command sudo ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node
and same result.

Comment: Do you get any output from `node --version` ? Also I would recommend updating npm to the latest version `sudo npm install -g npm`

Comment: No output for the version, and it didn't help

Comment: if `nodejs --version` does give an output it means the symlink hasn't worked, you could try apt-get install nodejs-legacy to automatically make this for you. If this still doesn't work I would recommend the NVM route suggested in this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21168141/cannot-install-packages-using-node-package-manager-in-ubuntu

Comment: Thanks. apt-get install nodejs-legacy helped!

Comment: Glad to help :) Please can you accept my answer if your issue is resolved