# `yo angular` gives error: npm ERR! code ENOENT npm ERR! errno 34 (yes I have cleaned the cache and set .npmignore)

Tags: node.js, angularjs, npm, yeoman, yeoman-generator

I tried to run `yo angular` in a new project directory, but it gave me the ENOENT error somewhere along the way. Yes I have looked at [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17990647/npm-install-errors-with-error-enoent-chmod), but its solution doesn't work for me.

I ran these things on the empty new project directory right before running `yo angular`:

```
touch .npmignore
npm cache clear
npm cache clean
```

But I still get:

```
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, lstat '/home/ubuntu/app_c/node_modules/grunt/    internal-tasks/bump.js'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log, 
npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! System Linux 3.2.0-54-virtual
npm ERR! command "/home/ubuntu/local/bin/node" "/home/ubuntu/local/bin/  npm" "install"
npm ERR! cwd /home/ubuntu/app_c
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.26
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.3
npm ERR! path /home/ubuntu/app_c/node_modules/grunt/internal-tasks/bump. js
npm ERR! fstream_path /home/ubuntu/app_c/node_modules/grunt/internal-    tasks/bump.js
npm ERR! fstream_type File 
npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! fstream_stack /home/ubuntu/local/lib/node_modules/npm/          node_modules/fstream/lib/writer.js:284:26
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
```

How can I fix it?

---

Here is the [history of ALL the commands, in chronological order, that I ran](https://gist.github.com/randwa1k/9167694) on a brand new Ubuntu Server 12.04.3, so you can see exactly what led up to this point, and where I have installed various packages.

This question is linked to an npm [github issue](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/4764).

Comment: after `npm cache clean` try reinstalling yo.

Comment: On a new directory, after `npm cache clean`, I did both `npm install -g yo` and `npm install -g generator-angular`. And did `npm cache clean` again before running `yo angular`. I still get the ENOENT.

Comment: I've just had the strictly the same problem. "npm update -g" fixed it for me.

Comment: npm cache clean worked for me!

Answer (score 27):

EDIT: `npm update -g` followed by `npm cache clear` should work for most. However, when first installing on Mac OS you may need to navigate to your `usr/local/lib/node_modules` folder once nodeJS is first installed and grant read/write permission to "Everyone". Node won't be able to installed additional workflow components globally until those permissions are released. You don't want to sudo the npm install commands, because then those tools won't have sudo access to run after the fact. Read/write permissions are changed by right-clicking the folder and going to "Get info" then changing permissions at bottom of popup.

I had this same issue on Windows 7 machine. Here are the steps I took to resolve:

- repair Node installation
- open elevated cli
- run `npm update -g`
- run `npm cache clear`
- run `npm install -g yo`
- run `npm cache clear`
- run `npm install -g generator-angular`
- run `npm cache clear`
- created new directory
- run `yo angular test`
- run `npm cache clear`
- run `grunt serve`

I did run into some other issues with karma.conf.js where the paths had a `\` instead of `/` for bower_components. Also, I noticed the optional angular modules were injected in my app.js despite not including them all in my yo build from the cli. I have reported these issues on github.

Comment: Thanks - this worked for me on Mac OS X. Everything had been working fine until yeoman started complaining about me trying to run it with sudo. The npm path changes I had to make must have left everything in a mess, but this sorted it out...

Comment: This fixed it for me. I think the key step was `npm update -g` followed by `npm cache clear`.

Comment: `npm update -g` and `npm cache clear` also fixed this for me. I was able to successfully `yo angular` once these finished.

Answer (score 2):

> npm ERR! command "/home/ubuntu/local/bin/node"

Are you installing in a user directory?  I did and had ENOENT errors too.

I had to mkdir some directories.  If they're not there, try creating some of the directories in the debug.log, like lib/node_modules.

Answer (score 1):

Update node (and npm) to the latest version, and this should solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

These `ENOENT` (and sometimes `EACCES`) errors are often caused by old versions of `npm`.  Unfortunately even the latest version of `node` does not distribute the current version of `npm`.

After installing `node`, run `npm -v`.  If you don't see `2.1.18` or later, you should upgrade following the official instructions here https://github.com/npm/npm/wiki/Troubleshooting#try-the-latest-stable-version-of-npm

On OSX the quick way to upgrade is `sudo npm install -g npm@latest`

On Windows, follow the guide in the wiki or read this answer [How do I update npm on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26908899/how-do-i-update-npm-on-windows)

`cmd.exe
cd C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs
npm install npm@latest`

Answer (score 0):

My problem was a broken **package.json**. Maybe this will help someone.

Answer (score 0):

This problem can really be caused by several things and it is strange that npm is not able to give the exact cause of the problem.

In my case, this problem was caused by importing a scss file. The specified path was not correct.