# yo angular cannot find module bower-config

Tags: angularjs, yeoman

I'm trying to get started the first time with yeoman. I want to create an angular app using the command:

```
yo angular
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
Error: Cannot find module '/Users/mel/workspaces/protractor-techevent/node_modules/bower-config'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
at require (module.js:380:17)
at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-angular/node_modules/wiredep/node_modules/modmod/index.js:5:16
at Array.reduce (native)
at module.exports (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-angular/node_modules/wiredep/node_modules/modmod/index.js:3:35)
at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-angular/node_modules/wiredep/wiredep.js:3:26)
at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
```

I checked the yeoman faq, googled but couldn't find an answer. Does anybody have an idea?

Using OS X 10.9.4, npm 1.4.23, yeoman 1.2.1 (doctor says its ok), generator-angular 0.9.5, bower 1.3.9

Comment: are you behind a firewall or corporate proxy?

Comment: no, just disabled little snitch to make sure

Comment: did whats recommended for windows and it works now: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21964874/yo-angular-gives-error-npm-err-code-enoent-npm-err-errno-34-yes-i-have-cle

Answer (score 2):

That means the Node module "bower-config" is missing.

Run "npm install bower-config". And I guess "chalk" module will be missing too.

Try to re-install bower manually "npm install -g bower", this should resolve all the missing depencies.

Maybe you will also need to run

```
npm update -g
```