# `yo office` gives error Spawn git ENONENT

Tags: office-js, yeoman, office-addins, yeoman-generator

I am using the yeoman-generator office as per the official docs

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/quickstarts/project-quickstart

Node: Version :10.16.0 (LTS)

Ran the following command. No error

`npm install -g yo generator-office`

But when I try to run

`yo office`

getting the following error

[image]

Trying hard for more than a day. Removed npm cache and followed the similar issue [`yo angular` gives error: npm ERR! code ENOENT npm ERR! errno 34 (yes I have cleaned the cache and set .npmignore)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21964874/yo-angular-gives-error-npm-err-code-enoent-npm-err-errno-34-yes-i-have-cle)

Also, downgraded node version to v8 and npm downgraded, tried almost all configuration possibilities

but nothing seems to work. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @Ragavan Rajan for reaching out, and for using the Yo Office! There is an o[pen issue](https://github.com/OfficeDev/generator-office/issues/414) with Yo Office that it requires the [git client](https://git-scm.com/downloads) to be installed.

We are in the process of looking for a solution, but in the mean time, if you are able to install the git client this will fix the problem. Another option is that you can download the templates from their respective repos directly using the zip files from the repo. Detail's on the locations of the different repos for the templates are located in [the configuration file](https://github.com/OfficeDev/generator-office/blob/master/src/app/config/projectProperties.json) that comes along with Yo Office.

I hope this helps you! Feel free to add your comments and your error details to the issue as well. Our team will try and provide a better alternative soon. Thank you again for using Yo Office and building on the Office Platform!

Comment: Interesting fact is I have git installed on my machine with the version of 2.20.0. I have uninstalled the git client and reinstalled the version 2.22.0 and then my `yo office` command works

Comment: That's great info to add to the [Open Issue here](https://github.com/OfficeDev/generator-office/issues/414) @Ragavan if you can. I am glad it worked! If you can signal StackOverflow with a bump-up on the vote, that would be helpful to other people who have the same issue.  Cheers!