# Ghost CMS - sudo npm install --production - Error

Tags: node.js, npm, blogs, ghost

i am trying to install ghost cms on a local vagrant box.

After i type in "sudo npm install --production" i get this error:

```
npm ERR! Linux 3.16.0-4-amd64
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "--production"

npm ERR! node v4.2.3

npm ERR! npm  v3.5.1

`npm ERR! path /var/www/html/ghost/node_modules/node-pre-

`gyp/node_modules/rc/node_modules/strip-json-comments/cli.js
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! syscall chmod

npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, chmod '/var/www/html/ghost/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/node_modules/rc/node_modules/strip-json-comments/cli.js'
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, chmod '/var/www/html/ghost/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/node_modules/rc/node_modules/strip-json-comments/cli.js'
npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Did you ever solve this? Having the same issue...

Comment: I thintk it might be the same thing as: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17990647/npm-install-errors-with-error-enoent-chmod

Comment: also having this problem -- any update?

Answer (score 1):

I was running into the same problem, and I fixed it by running the following in `/usr/bin`

```
$ sudo apt install nodejs-legacy
```

Once installed, head back over to your ghost installation directory, and re-run `sudo npm install --production`