# Error while installing yeoman

Tags: ubuntu, npm, yo

I am trying to install yo on my ubuntu v16.4 LTS but i get this error:

```
npm WARN deprecated npmconf@2.1.2: this package has been reintegrated into npm and is now out of date with respect to npm
npm ERR! Linux 4.4.0-22-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "yo"
npm ERR! node v6.2.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.9.0
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/lib/cli.js
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! syscall chmod

npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, chmod '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/lib/cli.js'
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, chmod '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/lib/cli.js'
npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/momor1/npm-debug.log
```

As you see, I have the latest npm and nodejs, and I am in root mode so I still don't get it why its throwing this error. Any help please:)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/17990647/297087

Comment: Ok, i am also getting same error :(, please let me know if you fixed the issue.

Comment: I have the same error on OS X 10.11.5 (El Capitan) with Node 4.4.4 and nam 3.9.0. Clean install from `node-v4.4.4.pkg`.

Comment: thats really wierd! @ChristianJunk

Comment: Same issue on Ubuntu 14.04. Tried node v0.12 and node v6.x from nodesource ppa https://github.com/nodesource/distributions.

Comment: Does this happen with other global installations too?

Comment: Yeah, its happening with global installations too

Comment: How did you install nodejs?

Comment: @littlepootis  from ubuntu terminal and i have the latest version 6.2

Comment: Apparently, this is a bug that hasn't been fixed yet: https://github.com/yeoman/yo/issues/437

Comment: yeah i can see this now

Comment: My real issue was `sudo grunt serve` was not working. I have fixed it using  `"grunt-connect-proxy": "git://github.com/ruiaraujo/grunt-connect-proxy#patch-1",` Ref :- https://github.com/drewzboto/grunt-connect-proxy/issues/95

Comment: did u install the latest version? 1.8.2 ?

Comment: No, i haven't mentioned the version in package just `"grunt-connect-proxy": "git://github.com/ruiaraujo/grunt-connect-proxy#patch-1",`

Answer (score 13):

It seems that this error occurs when you are trying to install the latest version, which was released today (2016/04/18): [1.8.2](https://github.com/yeoman/yo/releases/tag/v1.8.2)

Please try to install the **previous** version:

```
sudo npm install -g yo@1.8.1
```

This is working for me now. Tested on a clean virtual machine with OS X El Capitan v10.11.2, node 4.4.4 and npm 3.9.0 and on my developer machine with OS X 10.11.5.

Comment: This worked for me. @Kob_24 try `npm cache clean` first? I was able to confirm on my build server that the problem started once the yo package was upgraded from 1.8.1 to 1.8.2

Comment: i still get the same even if i do npm cache clean, how did you upgrade from 18.1 to 1.8.2?

Comment: YSK it's considered a Bad Idea to install npm modules with sudo; here are instructions for working around it http://www.competa.com/blog/2014/12/how-to-run-npm-without-sudo/

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @jcollum to help me find the solution, the problem was that `yo` needed to install some plugins in sudo mode (this was not possible since installation was automatic by yo). Setting the prefix of npm to `home` would solve the issue of using sudo each time u need to install new package. Just follow this tutorial and you should be able to install `yo@1.8.3`. Best of Luck http://www.competa.com/blog/2014/12/how-to-run-npm-without-sudo/