# Trouble deploying KeystoneJS on Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, keystonejs

I have a KeystoneJS application I'm trying to deploy on Elastic Beanstalk on a t2.micro instance. During the deployment process, the deployment is erroring with the following output in eb-activity.log:

```
> kerberos@0.0.11 install /tmp/deployment/application/node_modules/keystone/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/kerberos
> (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)


Running npm install: /opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-v4.4.3-linux-x64/bin/npm
Setting npm config jobs to 1
npm config jobs set to 1
Running npm with --production flag
Failed to run npm install. Snapshot logs for more details.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/containerfiles/ebnode.py", line 681, in 
main()
File "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/containerfiles/ebnode.py", line 663, in main
node_version_manager.run_npm_install(options.app_path)
File "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/containerfiles/ebnode.py", line 131, in run_npm_install
self.npm_install(bin_path, self.config_manager.get_container_config('app_staging_dir'))
File "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/containerfiles/ebnode.py", line 166, in npm_install
raise e
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-v4.4.3-linux-x64/bin/npm', '--production', 'install']' returned non-zero exit status -9.
```

I have also checked the npm-debug.log and see the following:

```
127706 info install kerberos@0.0.11
127707 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry _baseAssign.js
127708 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry _assignInDefaults.js
127709 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry unzip.js
127710 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry uniq.js
127711 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry _baseGt.js
127712 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry tap.js
127713 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry _baseFor.js
127714 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry toFinite.js
127715 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry _baseFor.js
127716 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry toFinite.js
127717 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry es6/weak-map.js
127718 silly gunzTarPerm modified mode [ 'es6/weak-map.js', 438, 420 ]
127719 verbose unsafe-perm in lifecycle false
127720 verbose stack Error: spawn ENOMEM
127720 verbose stack     at exports._errnoException (util.js:870:11)
127720 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.spawn (internal/child_process.js:298:11)
127720 verbose stack     at exports.spawn (child_process.js:362:9)
127720 verbose stack     at spawn (/opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-v4.4.3-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/spawn.js:7:13)
127720 verbose stack     at runCmd_ (/opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-v4.4.3-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/lifecycle.js:211:14)
127720 verbose stack     at /opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-v4.4.3-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/lifecycle.js:179:7
127720 verbose stack     at nextTickCallbackWith0Args (node.js:420:9)
127720 verbose stack     at process._tickCallback (node.js:349:13)
127721 verbose cwd /tmp/deployment/application
127722 error Linux 4.4.8-20.46.amzn1.x86_64
127723 error argv "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-v4.4.3-linux-x64/bin/node" "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-v4.4.3-linux-x64/bin/npm" "--production" "install"
127724 error node v4.4.3
127725 error npm  v2.15.1
127726 error code ENOMEM
127727 error errno ENOMEM
127728 error syscall spawn
127729 error spawn ENOMEM
127730 error If you need help, you may report this error at:
127730 error     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
127731 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

This also occurs if I increase the instance size to t2.small. Are these instances insufficient to install KeystoneJS?

Comment: having the same problem but with installing dtrace-provider :/

Answer (score 0):

It could be an issue with your gitignore / npmignore. I would try putting a black .npmignore in your project root.

If there is no .npmignore in a project, npm defaults to using .gitignore

https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/developers#keeping-files-out-of-your-package

StackOverflow reference : [npm install errors with Error: ENOENT, chmod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17990647/npm-install-errors-with-error-enoent-chmod)

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't fix the issue.