# Unable to install react-native-gifted-chat

Tags: react-native

I have run `"npm install react-native-gifted-chat  --save"` but got this error.

```
>C:\UserConsultantMachenism>npm install react-native-gifted-chat --save
npm WARN addRemoteGit Error: spawn git ENOENT
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at exports._errnoException (util.js:1012:11)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:182:32)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:348:16)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
npm WARN addRemoteGit  git+https://github.com/FaridSafi/react-native-action-sheet.git resetting remote C:\Users\Faber\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-https-github-com-FaridSafi-react-native-action-sheet-git-79de8fec because of error: { Error: spawn git ENOENT
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at exports._errnoException (util.js:1012:11)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:182:32)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:348:16)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
npm WARN addRemoteGit   code: 'ENOENT',
npm WARN addRemoteGit   errno: 'ENOENT',
npm WARN addRemoteGit   syscall: 'spawn git',
npm WARN addRemoteGit   path: 'git',
npm WARN addRemoteGit   spawnargs:
npm WARN addRemoteGit    [ '-c',
npm WARN addRemoteGit      'core.longpaths=true',
npm WARN addRemoteGit      'config',
npm WARN addRemoteGit      '--get',
npm WARN addRemoteGit      'remote.origin.url' ],
npm WARN addRemoteGit   cmd: 'git -c core.longpaths=true config --get remote.origin.url' }
npm ERR! git clone --template=C:\Users\Faber\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\_templates --mirror https://github.com/FaridSafi/react-native-action-sheet.git C:\Users\Faber\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-https-github-com-FaridSafi-react-native-action-sheet-git-79de8fec:
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.14393
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "react-native-gifted-chat" "--save"
npm ERR! node v6.3.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.3
npm ERR! path git
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn git

>npm ERR! enoent spawn git ENOENT
npm ERR! enoent spawn git ENOENT
npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

>npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\UserConsultantMachenism\npm-debug.log
```

Can you please help me to resolve this?

Comment: Works on my machine(mac node 4.x npm 3.9). So repository is ok. Maybe a problem with cache or ssl.

Comment: What version of NPM are you using? maybe try `npm install -g npm`.

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18020195/4306508

Comment: i am using 2.15.9 .