# npm -v Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, mkdir 'E:\' 6.14.4

Tags: vue.js

[image]

[image]

I just installed NPM. I don't know what to do. I've checked it all afternoon. Help me. Thank you. I've reinstalled it several times and tried many solutions. It's not easy.

I've tried the following
npm rebuild node-sass

npm install npm -g

sudo npm install -g npm

npm install -g npm

npm cache clear

npm cache verify

Npm install -g bower

Whatever I type, he answers me 
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, mkdir 'E:\'
I'm really upset. Please help me

I've seen people say that re downloading can solve the problem. But clean up the registry. So I did it according to the plan, uninstalled node, downloaded regclean pro, and cleaned the registry. But it's still useless. I'll check the others. I sincerely look forward to your help.

Comment: Did you search at all? There are many questions about this already on SO. What did you already try, so that people don't repeat the same answers to you?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [npm install errors with Error: ENOENT, chmod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17990647/npm-install-errors-with-error-enoent-chmod)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but my question hasn't been solved. I'm still trying to search for the answer。

Comment: I've tried the following

Comment: npm rebuild node-sass
npm install npm -g
sudo npm install -g npm
npm install -g npm
npm cache clear
npm cache verify
Npm install -g bower
Whatever I type, he answers me 
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, mkdir 'E:\'
I'm really upset. Please help me

Comment: I also try to see if it's an environmental variable.

And search for some commands to reinstall NPM.

The same answer after trying. I'm broken. Thank you for your reply. I used stack overflow for the first time.

Also try to go to the official website to download a lower version.

I don't have an e-disk in my computer. I don't know why

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been solved. I also tried to modify D: \ nodejs \ node_ Under modules \ NPM

. npmrc file.

Finally, modify the. Npmrc file under C: \ users \ administrator

prefix=D:\ node.js \node_ global

cache=D:\ node.js \node_ cache

registry= http://registry.cnpmjs.org/

python=python2.7

msvs_ version=2015

It's done