# New to react could not start server got error messages any idea?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, web-development-server

PS C:\Users\USER\Desktop\react> npm start
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path C:\Users\USER\Desktop\react\package.json
npm ERR! errno -4058
'C:\Users\USER\Desktop\react\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2020-10-15T10_23_32_090Z-debug.log

Comment: check this `https://stackoverflow.com/a/18020195/2739391`. even if you provide more details that will be good like what command you use to create react project which dependency installed ? check npm and node versions.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to run an npm script such as "npm start" in a folder that doesn't have a "package.json" file. Make sure you are in your React project's working directory and try again.

Comment: I use vs code .you mean changing workspace folder . where react project might help!

Comment: Is your project directly inside `C:\Users\USER\Desktop\react` or is it in another folder inside it?