# How fix error npm "This is related to npm not being able to find a file" in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, npm

I want to work with Laravel Broadcasting and follow the instructions, I created a completely new Laravel 8.12 project and try to run with npm run dev command, but I get errors:

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn sh
npm ERR! path /Users/administrator/procob
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! enoent spawn sh ENOENT
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent
```

My package.json:

```
{
"private": true,
"scripts": {
    "dev": "npm run development",
    "development": "mix",
    "watch": "mix watch",
    "watch-poll": "mix watch -- --watch-options-poll=1000",
    "hot": "mix watch --hot",
    "prod": "npm run production",
    "production": "mix --production"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.21",
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "jquery": "^3.2",
    "laravel-echo": "^1.10.0",
    "laravel-mix": "^6.0.11",
    "lodash": "^4.17.19",
    "popper.js": "^1.12",
    "postcss": "^8.1.14",
    "pusher-js": "^7.0.3",
    "resolve-url-loader": "^3.1.2",
    "sass": "^1.20.1",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.0",
    "vue": "^2.5.17",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.10",
    "webpack": "^5.20.2"
}
```

}

And full error

```
22 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit 
(internal/child_process.js:269:19)
22 verbose stack     at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:465:16)
22 verbose stack     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21)
23 verbose cwd /Users/administrator/procob
24 verbose Darwin 20.2.0
25 verbose argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "dev"
26 verbose node v14.15.4
27 verbose npm  v7.5.2
28 error code ENOENT
29 error syscall spawn sh
30 error path /Users/administrator/procob
31 error errno -2
32 error enoent spawn sh ENOENT
33 error enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
34 verbose exit -2
```

I will be glad for any help!

Comment: Probably This may Help you [npm install errors with Error: ENOENT, chmod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17990647/npm-install-errors-with-error-enoent-chmod/18020195)

Comment: Delete node_modules folder and run ```npm install``` again.

Comment: I was deleting node_modules and clearing the cache but it didn't help

Comment: use `yarn` pm instead. delete `node_modules` and run `yarn`

Comment: I had 2 versions of npm, I was able to get the paths via the which node command. I completely uninstalled Node and re-installed, this solved the problem