# ENOENT errors when installing npm modules

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

Just getting started with npm, I already have a project folder I'd like to use. On Windows 10 Pro (Version 2004).

- Node.js version 16.13.1
- npm version 8.1.2.

I've deleted the npm cache folder and package.lock.json. Here's the non verbose output when I type "**npm install sass**"

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall lstat
npm ERR! path D:\
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! enoent Invalid response body while trying to fetch https://registry.npmjs.org/sass: ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'D:\'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent
```

And the verbose output when I type "**npm install sass --verbose**"

```
C:\Users\username\Desktop\portfolio>npm install sass --verbose
npm verb cli [
npm verb cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
npm verb cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
npm verb cli   'install',
npm verb cli   'sass',
npm verb cli   '--verbose'
npm verb cli ]
npm info using npm@8.1.2
npm info using node@v16.13.1
npm timing npm:load:whichnode Completed in 1ms
npm timing config:load:defaults Completed in 1ms
npm timing config:load:file:C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\npmrc Completed in 3ms
npm timing config:load:builtin Completed in 3ms
npm timing config:load:cli Completed in 2ms
npm timing config:load:env Completed in 0ms
npm timing config:load:file:C:\Users\username\Desktop\portfolio\.npmrc Completed in 0ms
npm timing config:load:project Completed in 1ms
npm timing config:load:file:C:\Users\username\.npmrc Completed in 1ms
npm timing config:load:user Completed in 1ms
npm timing config:load:file:C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm\etc\npmrc Completed in 0ms
npm timing config:load:global Completed in 0ms
npm timing config:load:validate Completed in 0ms
npm timing config:load:credentials Completed in 1ms
npm timing config:load:setEnvs Completed in 1ms
npm timing config:load Completed in 10ms
npm timing npm:load:configload Completed in 10ms
npm timing npm:load:setTitle Completed in 0ms
npm timing npm:load:setupLog Completed in 0ms
npm timing config:load:flatten Completed in 2ms
npm timing npm:load:cleanupLog Completed in 3ms
npm timing npm:load:configScope Completed in 0ms
npm timing npm:load:projectScope Completed in 1ms
npm timing npm:load Completed in 32ms
npm timing arborist:ctor Completed in 1ms
npm timing arborist:ctor Completed in 0ms
npm timing idealTree:init Completed in 11ms
npm timing idealTree:userRequests Completed in 2ms
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/sass 177ms (cache miss)
npm timing idealTree:#root Completed in 183ms
npm timing idealTree:node_modules/sass Completed in 0ms
npm timing idealTree:buildDeps Completed in 185ms
npm timing idealTree:fixDepFlags Completed in 1ms
npm timing idealTree Completed in 204ms
npm timing command:install Completed in 245ms
npm verb type system
npm verb stack FetchError: Invalid response body while trying to fetch https://registry.npmjs.org/sass: ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'D:\'
npm verb stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\minipass-fetch\lib\body.js:162:15
npm verb stack     at async Arborist.[nodeFromEdge] (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\arborist\lib\arborist\build-ideal-tree.js:1061:19)
npm verb stack     at async Arborist.[buildDepStep] (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\arborist\lib\arborist\build-ideal-tree.js:930:11)
npm verb stack     at async Arborist.buildIdealTree (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\arborist\lib\arborist\build-ideal-tree.js:216:7)
npm verb stack     at async Promise.all (index 1)
npm verb stack     at async Arborist.reify (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\arborist\lib\arborist\reify.js:149:5)
npm verb stack     at async Install.install (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\install.js:170:5)
npm verb cwd C:\Users\username\Desktop\portfolio
npm verb Windows_NT 10.0.19041
npm verb argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "sass" "--verbose"
npm verb node v16.13.1
npm verb npm  v8.1.2
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall lstat
npm ERR! path D:\
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! enoent Invalid response body while trying to fetch https://registry.npmjs.org/sass: ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'D:\'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent
npm verb exit 1
npm timing npm Completed in 618ms
npm verb unfinished npm timer reify 1640373695460
npm verb unfinished npm timer reify:loadTrees 1640373695497
npm verb code 1
```

Any clues as to what I'm doing wrong? There is no "D:" disk on my system. I have a local "C:" SSD drive and two external "E:" and "F:" drives.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Have you tried to work this in a virtual environment or online IDE like replit because I am not able to replicate this issue.

Comment: @VarunW. Hey Varun W., I switched to yarn in the end and it worked. Should I keep this question open in case other people face similar issues?

Comment: If you believe that this question will help others and that it is not similar to any other questions then dont close it.

Answer (score -1):

When you use this command:

```
npm install sass
```

It might not work because it goes through the npm and sometimes it won't work if it is unlisted or has security problems.

```
yarn add sass
```

Should work because it will install in a different file so it won't affect the file which you are having problems with also unlike nom yarn also installs your package directly from github if it cant find or has an error in npm.

Answer (score -1):

This question is duplicate and well answered here [npm install errors with Error: ENOENT, chmod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17990647/npm-install-errors-with-error-enoent-chmod?page=1&tab=trending#tab-top)

Answer (score -1):

npm -v
-- check version

npm install -g npm

-- update or install

I have done like this

Comment: And... did it fix the problem? Please read [answer].