# changing path of "npm start" script

Tags: reactjs, npm, npm-start

```
PS C:\Users\TITAS\Desktop\Present Connection\ReactASPNET-master> npm start
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path C:\Users\TITAS\Desktop\Present Connection\ReactASPNET-master/package.json
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\TITAS\Desktop\Present Connection\ReactASPNET-master\package.json'   
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
```

Is it possible to change the path in the above? It should be:

```
path C:\Users\TITAS\Desktop\Present Connection\ReactASPNET-master/react-ui-crud/package.json
```

Comment: Not sure I understand the problem. If you want to use `package.json` in `C:\Users\TITAS\Desktop\Present Connection\ReactASPNET-master/react-ui-crud/package.json` do `cd C:\Users\TITAS\Desktop\Present Connection\ReactASPNET-master/react-ui-crud` before running `npm start`

Comment: @apokryfos it seems like it works. thanks :)

Comment: check this : [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17990647/npm-install-errors-with-error-enoent-chmod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17990647/npm-install-errors-with-error-enoent-chmod)